# docker ubuntu cron -f is not working

Tags: ubuntu, cron, docker

Trying to run a cron job in a docker container.
HAve a supervisord properly configured
(I see `cron -f` in the `ps -ef` and if I kill it it respawns)

crontab file (for testing):
`* * * * * echo hi >> /root/test`

I tried putting it in `/etc/cron.d/crontab` `/etc/crontab` and in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/crontab`

Nothing is working - I'm not getting anything in `/root/test`

Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to stick a syslog daemon in your container to see if `crond` is logging any errors.  You also may need to check your crontab syntax; crontab files in places like `/etc/crontab` require an extra username field (e.g., `* * * * * root echo hi >> /root/test`).

Comment: Indeed it was the extra username. Thanks! wanna submit it as an answer?

Comment: Glad it helped. Posted!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You may want to check your crontab syntax; crontab files in places like `/etc/crontab` require an extra username field, for example:

```
* * * * * root echo hi >> /root/test
```

This is documented (not very prominently) in `crontab(5)`:

> **Jobs in /etc/cron.d/**
>
> The jobs in cron.d and /etc/crontab are system jobs, which are used  usually  for  more
>    than  one user, thus, additionally the username is needed....