# How to run a cron job inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, cron, containers, sh

I am trying to run a cronjob inside a docker container that invokes a shell script.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 625, accepted):

You can copy your `crontab` into an image, in order for the container launched from said image to run the job.

---

**Important**: as noted in [docker-cron issue 3](https://github.com/Ekito/docker-cron/issues/3): use [LF, not CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1552749/6309) for your `cron` file.

---

See "[Run a cron job with Docker](https://github.com/Ekito/docker-cron)" from [Julien Boulay](https://github.com/julienboulay) in his [**`Ekito/docker-cron`**](https://github.com/Ekito/docker-cron):

> Let’s create a new file called "`hello-cron`" to describe our job.

```
# must be ended with a new line "LF" (Unix) and not "CRLF" (Windows)
* * * * * echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# An empty line is required at the end of this file for a valid cron file.
```

If you are wondering what is `2>&1`, [Ayman Hourieh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40005/ayman-hourieh) [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/818284).

> The following Dockerfile describes all the steps to build your image

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER docker@ekito.fr

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron

# Copy hello-cron file to the cron.d directory
COPY hello-cron /etc/cron.d/hello-cron
 
# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Apply cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron
 
# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
 
# Run the command on container startup
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

**But: if `cron` dies,** the container [keeps running](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/f17b2cefc6e673e979850d79b265f345).

(see [Gaafar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3716153/gaafar)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container/37458519?noredirect=1#comment67411829_37458519) and [How do I make `apt-get` install less noisy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258219/how-do-i-make-apt-get-install-less-noisy#comment326577_258226):
`apt-get -y install -qq --force-yes cron` can work too)

As noted by [Nathan Lloyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3417592/nathan-lloyd) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container/37458519#comment107451752_37458519):

> Quick note about a gotcha:
> If you're adding a script file and telling cron to run it, remember to
> **`RUN chmod 0744 /the_script`**
> **Cron fails silently if you forget**.

---

OR, make sure your job itself redirect directly to stdout/stderr instead of a log file, as described in [hugoShaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7906071/hugoshaka)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46220104/6309):

```
 * * * * * root echo hello > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```

Replace the last Dockerfile line with

```
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

**But: it doesn't work if** you want to run tasks [as a non-root](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/336fd3185de7e168023867302d5ac99b).

See also (about `cron -f`, which is to say cron "foreground") "[docker ubuntu `cron -f` is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30529057/6309)"

---

Build and run it:

```
sudo docker build --rm -t ekito/cron-example .
sudo docker run -t -i ekito/cron-example
```

> Be patient, wait for 2 minutes and your command-line should display:

```
Hello world
Hello world
```

---

[Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032870/eric) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container/37458519#comment84898391_37458519):

> Do note that `tail` may not display the correct file if it is created during image build.
> If that is the case, you need to create or touch the file during container runtime in order for tail to pick up the correct file.

See "[Output of `tail -f` at the end of a docker `CMD` is not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43807880/6309)".

---

See more in "[**Running Cron in Docker**](https://blog.thesparktree.com/cron-in-docker)" (Apr. 2021) from [**Jason Kulatunga**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1157633/jason-kulatunga), as he [commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container/37458519#comment118918017_37458519)

See Jason's image [`AnalogJ/docker-cron`](https://github.com/AnalogJ/docker-cron) based on:

- Dockerfile installing `cronie`/`crond`, depending on distribution.
- an entrypoint initializing `/etc/environment` and then calling

  ```
  cron -f -l 2
  ```

Comment: I had first to install cron, as it is not included. But by adding this to the Dockerfile it works. Thanks!
`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install cron`

Comment: @CHeyer OK, I have updated the answer to include the missing `RUN` command.

Comment: you should probably add `-y` to installing cron to avoid docker build exiting

Comment: @Gaafar Strange, I don't see a -y option in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html

Comment: i mean `apt-get install -y cron` to avoid the install promting for `y` or `n`

Comment: @Gaafar Right! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility and added another option.

Comment: Has anyone tried this on a Vagrant VM with Docker Compose as provisioner? I cant get it to run, no matter what..

Comment: @LePhleg It is better to make that an actual question on its own instead of a comment.

Comment: Many thanks @VonC. How would you edit this to create create crontab from a file? I've been doing `RUN crontab -u root cron_files.txt` and I've tried `ADD crontab cron_files.txt /etc/cron.d/feeds` but when I try to do `chmod` it returns `chmod: cannot access '/etc/cron.d/feeds': No such file or directory`

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu 14.04 and it didn't work. The output is empty.

Comment: @Pangur nothing in `docker ps` or `docker logs`? If so, please ask a new question.

Comment: @VonC docker ps showed running container, but one has nothing to do with it. I've found out the problem: my kernel was old enough and it caused known bug related to not only cron https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/issues/144 . After I've updated my kernel to 4.4 everything gone well. Other workaround was running under Ubuntu Precise but this one I don't need.

Comment: On certain hosts, I needed to touch the crontab files to pull them into the top layer.  CMD touch /etc/crontab /etc/cron.*/* /var/log/cron.log && cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log

Comment: The `root` must be added into cronjob record.

Comment: Does this solution still work? When I follow the guidelines given, when I log into the container as root and type `crontab -l`, I get **No crontab installed for root**, also, my screen remains blank. However, when I check '/etc/cron.d/', I see the crontab fiel is there (and even more surprisingly), when I check `/var/log/cron.log`, I see that the script is running (the file content is being appended with `Hello World`).  I'm pulling this image in my Dockerfile: `FROM phusion/baseimage:0.10.0`. Any ideas about the discrepancy in behaviour?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli It did run at the time. Can you ask a new question (with a link back to this one)?

Comment: Do note that `tail` may not display the correct file if it is created during image build. If that is the case, you need to create or `touch` the file during container runtime in order for `tail` to pick up the correct file. See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43807880/1032870

Comment: @Eric Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Also you need to add RUN /usr/bin/crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron in your Dockerfile to make it work

Comment: @RustamGaneyev Can you edit the answer in order to add that step?

Comment: @RustamGaneyev I just did: thank you for your contribution :)

Comment: As of 2018, this approach no longer works; has anyone been able to get their cronjob to work with Ubuntu as the base image? I'm not interested in the Alpine image which comes with cron running out of the box

Comment: What about running cron in a container while *not* being root?

Comment: @Shmarkus You would need another setup, like https://github.com/uber/makisu, https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/open-sourcing-gvisor-a-sandboxed-container-runtime or https://medium.com/lucjuggery/running-a-container-with-a-non-root-user-e35830d1f42a.

Comment: Anyone knows if this is possible using AWS Fargate ?

Comment: Quick note about a gotcha: if you're adding a script file and telling cron to run it, remember to `RUN chmod 0744 /the_script`. Cron fails silently if you forget.

Comment: @NathanLloyd Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Given the complexity of this answer, I think it makes sense to **consider** the work around of running the cron job on a local server and pushing updates to the docker registry with the local cron job.

Comment: I have read many guides on getting cron working in a Docker container and 4 hours later this one helped me because you mentioned the blank link in the cron file :)

Thank you!

Comment: Nothing on this page works.  It has been running for several minutes and the output is empty.

Comment: @Arrow_Raider Strange. Could you ask a separate question with details about your particular setup?

Comment: I removed root and then it worked.  This stuff is extremely frustrating for me.

Comment: I wrote a blog post that implements this advice (and other issues I found running cron in docker) into working docker images for multiple distros (ubuntu, alpine, centos): https://blog.thesparktree.com/cron-in-docker

Comment: @JasonKulatunga Thank you, very interesting. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: If I use CMD the container is only doing this job. I actually want t run a cron in an existing container already execution something else. Any hint how this can be achieved, so cron is only in the back?

Comment: @Tobias good question. Can you make it a separate question, with a link back to this one, for context?

Comment: Specifying cron job directly in build file worked for me `RUN (crontab -l ; echo "* * * * * echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log") | crontab`. Maybe because of difference in line endings on Windows

Comment: What are the last two args of `cron -f -l 2` supposed to do ? Is there a way to force cron command to log to stdout instead of syslog (that is usually disable in docker images?)

Comment: @digEmAll on the first part of your comment: https://github.com/AnalogJ/docker-cron/blob/e75add23dbd6de8508b771fd7a3265b324dd3876/alpine.dockerfile#L9: as a CMD, using shell form `[ "", "", ... ]`.

Comment: @digEmAll On the second part, it depends on the OS and how the cron service is configured: https://serverfault.com/a/562996/783

Comment: @VonC: I know that is the CMD, but I was wondering what `-l 2` do, when passed to cron command. According to "man cron" (on ubuntu) `-l` enables LSB compliance but doesn't accept a value "2"... be aware that I could be missing something really naive, I'm not a linux expert.
About the cron service cfg, the problem is that in the base ubuntu image we don't have `rsyslog.d`, so I don't know where the logs are sent at all... it doesn't matter though, I don't want to discuss this in comments, thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @digEmAll OK. Sorry for having misinterpreted your initial question.

Comment: @digEmAll Note the `crond` mentioned here is the BusyBox one, for the Alpine image. Not the regular Linux one. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412805/crond-log-level-meaning. `-l` is for "log level".

Comment: Your comment could be changed to `# must be ended with a new line "LF" (Unix) and not "CRLF" (Windows)` which took me hours to figure out ;-)

Comment: @CordKaldemeyer Good point. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Actually, I found the behavior of `crontab` quite weird because it normally checks for validity but in this case does not complain about a missing new line or the format when using `CRLF` which does not run the cronjob at all. Thanks anyway, for editing as it is one thing one just have to keep in mind!

Comment: Instead of adding gotcha I would edit the answer as `RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron` are wrong permissions and the line is confusing

Comment: @4xy Please, do edit the answer, it will clarify it, and help others.

Comment: Your answer is good enough if we're constrained by traditional `cron` implementations. But what if we aren't? Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75353647/52499). That also handles @Shmarkus concerns. I'd add a link to my answer to the beginning of yours, but I'm not sure you'll agree.

Answer (score 263):

The accepted answer ***may be dangerous in a production environment***.

> In docker you should only execute one process per container because if you don't, the process that forked and went background is not monitored and may stop without you knowing it.

When you use `CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log` the cron process basically fork in order to execute `cron` in background, the main process exits and let you execute `tailf` in foreground. The background cron process could stop or fail you won't notice, your container will still run silently and your orchestration tool will not restart it.

> You can avoid such a thing by redirecting directly the cron's commands output into your docker `stdout` and `stderr` which are located respectively in `/proc/1/fd/1` and `/proc/1/fd/2`.

Using basic shell redirects you may want to do something like this :

```
* * * * * root echo hello > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```

And your CMD will be : `CMD ["cron", "-f"]`

**But: this doesn't work if** you want to run tasks [as a non-root](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/336fd3185de7e168023867302d5ac99b).

Comment: Nice: `cron -f` is for "cron foreground". I have included your answer in mine above, for more visibility. +1

Comment: Let's say my program doesn't output anything. Can I still use this method and be sure my process isn't going to stop in the background?

Comment: @Arcsector this method avoid putting a process in the background, thats why it does not fails silently. Having a background process in a docker container is not simple. If you want to have a running background process you might want to use an init process to monitor the multiple processes you run in the container. Another way is to start the process into another container next to the main one called 'sidecar'. The best way is often to avoid multiple processes in the container.

Comment: This is a good solution and works well for us aside from one issue. When the container receives a SIGTERM signal it doesn't seem to wait for the scheduled process to finish and gracefully shutdown, instead it is killing the process which can cause issues.

Comment: This solution worked for me on Debian/Alpine/CentOS containers. This is the most "portable" solution. Thanks for this @hugoShaka

Comment: This works and is the MOST portable solution;  It also handles issues of Log Rotation and other things as it is echoing output!  BEAUTIFUL

Comment: This should be the excepted answer as it really keeps cron running in the foreground and does not use “tail” as the main process.

Comment: When cron runs as root but the cronjobs as a regular user, they aren't allowed to write to /proc/1/fd/. Has anybody found a solution? I'm trying to use two fifo files and tailing them but this has its own issues.

Comment: Hi. Is there a way to update this so that the output also goes to a log file?

Comment: @TheDataPanda Look into the command "tee". It writes io to a file and also std in/out.

Comment: Don't you think that traditional `cron` implementations are not `docker`-friendly? Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75353647/52499).

Comment: In an Azure Container Instance, use `> /proc/$(pidof cron)/fd/1 2>/proc/$(pidof cron)/fd/2`, as its logs show the logs of the cron process instead of the docker process.

Answer (score 226):

For those who wants to use a simple and lightweight image:

```
FROM alpine:3.6

# copy crontabs for root user
COPY config/cronjobs /etc/crontabs/root

# start crond with log level 8 in foreground, output to stderr
CMD ["crond", "-f", "-d", "8"]
```

Where *cronjobs* is the file that contains your cronjobs, in this form:

```
* * * * * echo "hello stackoverflow" >> /test_file 2>&1
# remember to end this file with an empty new line
```

But apparently you won't see `hello stackoverflow` in `docker logs`.

Comment: Simple, light and standard image based. This should be the accepted answer. Also use the `> /proc/1/fd/1 2> /proc/1/fd/2` redirection to access cronjobs output directly from the docker logs.

Comment: For people not using alpine: The crond supporting the `-d 8` parameter is not the standard cron, it is the crond command from busybox. For example from ubuntu, you can run this as `busybox crond -f -d 8`. For older versions you have to use `-L /dev/stdout/`.

Comment: For my need - emulating a production setting set of independently running cron jobs where I need to see what is happening - this is great.

Comment: I would give this +100 if I could. This is by far the best way to run cron jobs in a Docker environment.

Comment: Will the cron job run normally if I just run it with 

kubectl run my_instance_name --image gcr.io/my_image

Or do I have to do anything else?

Comment: can this be done entirely by docker-compose.yml with an `image:alpine`?

Comment: If you don't want to build a new image every time you change the cron job (or if you need multiple), you can just run Alpine and use a volume to set the cron. I tested it out using the following: `docker run -v ${PWD}/cronjobs:/etc/crontabs/root alpine:3.6 crond -f -d 8`.
@Groostav you can use a similar thing in Docker Compose.

Comment: `CMD ["crond"` or `CMD ["cron"`?

Comment: As said [here](https://gist.github.com/andyshinn/3ae01fa13cb64c9d36e7#gistcomment-3633541) you have to be very careful that `/etc/crontabs/root` is owned by `root` and `chmod` to `600`

Comment: The line sequence should be `LF` for cronjobs file to work.

Answer (score 65):

What @VonC has suggested is nice but I prefer doing all cron job configuration in one line. This would avoid cross platform issues like cronjob location and you don't need a separate cron file.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Install cron
RUN apt-get -y install cron

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Setup cron job
RUN (crontab -l ; echo "* * * * * echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log") | crontab

# Run the command on container startup
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

After running your docker container, you can make sure if cron service is working by:

```
# To check if the job is scheduled
docker exec -ti <your-container-id> bash -c "crontab -l"
# To check if the cron service is running
docker exec -ti <your-container-id> bash -c "pgrep cron"
```

If you prefer to have ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD, then you can substitute the CMD above with

```
ENTRYPOINT cron start && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

**But: if `cron` dies,** the container [keeps running](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/f17b2cefc6e673e979850d79b265f345).

Comment: `RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron` or else it will not be able to find package `cron`

Comment: Thanks Youness, you gave me the idea of doing the following, which worked in my case where each cron is specified in a different file:

    `RUN cat $APP_HOME/crons/* | crontab`

Like a charm :)

Comment: adding `cron` to an entrypoint script seems like the best option: ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]

Comment: Using 2 commands in your `ENTRYPOINT` is dangerous.  I believe the first one (`cron`) forks to the background, while 2nd one (`tail`) runs in the foreground.  If `cron` stops, you'll never know it.  If `tail` stops, then docker will notice.

Comment: That makes sense to some extent though you can add some monitoring/logging around it (with another entry point or some other monitoring mechanisms) to check the health status of the cron service

Answer (score 29):

There is another way to do it, is to use [Tasker](http://github.com/opsxcq/tasker), a task runner that has cron (a scheduler) support.

Why ? Sometimes to run a cron job, you have to mix, your base image (python, java, nodejs, ruby) with the crond. That means another image to maintain. Tasker avoid that by decoupling the crond and you container. You can just focus on the image that you want to execute your commands, and configure Tasker to use it.

Here an `docker-compose.yml` file, that will run some tasks for you

```
version: "2"

services:
    tasker:
        image: strm/tasker
        volumes:
            - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
        environment:
            configuration: |
                logging:
                    level:
                        ROOT: WARN
                        org.springframework.web: WARN
                        sh.strm: DEBUG
                schedule:
                    - every: minute
                      task: hello
                    - every: minute
                      task: helloFromPython
                    - every: minute
                      task: helloFromNode
                tasks:
                    docker:
                        - name: hello
                          image: debian:jessie
                          script:
                              - echo Hello world from Tasker
                        - name: helloFromPython
                          image: python:3-slim
                          script:
                              - python -c 'print("Hello world from python")'
                        - name: helloFromNode
                          image: node:8
                          script:
                              - node -e 'console.log("Hello from node")'
```

There are 3 tasks there, all of them will run every minute (`every: minute`), and each of them will execute the `script` code, inside the image defined in `image` section.

Just run `docker-compose up`, and see it working. Here is the Tasker repo with the full documentation:

http://github.com/opsxcq/tasker

Comment: Dockerception (running docker containers from another container) is a bad practice and should be limited to continuous integration.
A workaround would be to use `docker exec` on specified containers.

Comment: Tasker doesn't use docker in docker (Dind/Dockerception), note that is passed the docker socket as a mapping, all containers spawned are are in spawned in the daemon that tasker runs. And if you don't want to run tasker inside docker, you can just deploy it as any other application.

Comment: I don't get the advantages of using tasker. Seems really a overkill to me using java and sh*** just to run a cron job.

Comment: Mixing cron and the base image that you need (python/node for example) create a extra dependency that need to be maintained and deployed, in this scenario all jobs share the same container, it means that you have to worry about cleaning up everything after every job runs. Jobs running on tasker are idempotent, so you have less things to worry about.

Answer (score 20):

Though this aims to run jobs beside a running process in a container via Docker's `exec` interface, this may be of interest for you.

I've written a daemon that observes containers and schedules jobs, defined in their metadata, on them. Example:

```
version: '2'

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
  mysql:
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
      - ./database_dumps:/dumps
    labels:
      deck-chores.dump.command: sh -c "mysqldump --all-databases > /dumps/dump-$$(date -Idate)"
      deck-chores.dump.interval: daily
```

'Classic', cron-like configuration is also possible.

Here are the [docs](http://deck-chores.rtfd.io/), here's the [image repository](https://hub.docker.com/r/funkyfuture/deck-chores/).

Comment: Thank you. This answer is most right for the Docker containers environment. No any changes in Docker images, only adding special container for executing tasks, it works like command ```docker exec <container_name> <some_command>``` by schedule.

Comment: This is gold! A very elegant and easy-to-use solution, in the paradigm of containers. Getting rid of crutches.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using docker for windows, remember that you have to change your line-ending format from CRLF to LF (i.e. from dos to unix) if you intend on importing your crontab file from windows to your ubuntu container. If not, your cron-job won't work. Here's a working example:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix

# Add crontab file (from your windows host) to the cron directory
ADD cron/hello-cron /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Change line ending format to LF
RUN dos2unix /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Apply cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/hello-cron.log

# Run the command on container startup
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/hello-cron.log
```

This actually took me hours to figure out, as debugging cron jobs in docker containers is a tedious task. Hope it helps anyone else out there that can't get their code to work!

**But: if `cron` dies,** the container [keeps running](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/f17b2cefc6e673e979850d79b265f345).

Comment: This helped solve my issue when trying to get output redirection to work. A command like `cat /proc/1/status > /proc/1/fd/1` would return an error from crond stating `crond: USER root pid   6 cmd root cat /proc/1/status > /proc/1/fd/1: nonexistent directory/proc/1/fd/1`. Changing the line endings to Unix enabled me to run the command successfully. Thanks, this took me more than a few hours to figure out!

Answer (score 13):

[VonC's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) answer is pretty thorough. In addition I'd like to add one thing that helped me. If you just want to run a cron job without tailing a file, you'd be tempted to just remove the `&& tail -f /var/log/cron.log` from the cron command.

However this will cause the Docker container to exit shortly after running because when the cron command completes, Docker thinks the last command has exited and hence kills the container. This can be avoided by running cron in the foreground via `cron -f`.

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, none of the above answers worked for me, although all answers lead to the solution and eventually to my solution, here is the snippet if it helps someone. Thanks

This can be solved with the bash file, due to the layered architecture of the Docker, cron service doesn't get initiated with RUN/CMD/ENTRYPOINT commands.

Simply add a bash file which will initiate the cron and other services (if required)

**DockerFile**

```
FROM gradle:6.5.1-jdk11 AS build
# apt
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install cron
# Setup cron to run every minute to print (you can add/update your cron here)
RUN touch /var/log/cron-1.log
RUN (crontab -l ; echo "* * * * * echo testing cron.... >> /var/log/cron-1.log 2>&1") | crontab
# entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
CMD ["bash","entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
service cron start & tail -f /var/log/cron-2.log
```

If any other service is also required to run along with cron then add that service with `&` in the same command, for example: `/opt/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh & service cron start & tail -f /var/log/cron-2.log`

Once you will get into the docker container there you can see that `testing cron....` will be getting printed every minute in file: `/var/log/cron-1.log`

**But, if `cron` dies,** the container [keeps running](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/f17b2cefc6e673e979850d79b265f345).

Comment: Shouldn't it be doing `tail -f /var/log/cron-1.log` instead of `/var/log/cron-2.log`, since `cron-1.log` is where the STDOUT/STDERR is being directed? (Unless I'm missing something)

Comment: Yes, correct, that was a typo, `/var/log/cron-1.log` should be at every place

Answer (score 10):

I created a Docker image based on the other answers, which can be used like

```sh
docker run -v "/path/to/cron:/etc/cron.d/crontab" gaafar/cron
```

where `/path/to/cron`: absolute path to crontab file, or you can use it as a base in a Dockerfile:

```
FROM gaafar/cron

# COPY crontab file in the cron directory
COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

# Add your commands here
```

For reference, the image [is here](https://hub.docker.com/r/gaafar/cron/).

Answer (score 6):

Define the cronjob in a dedicated container which runs the command via docker exec to your service.

This is higher cohesion and the running script will have access to the environment variables you have defined for your service.

```
#docker-compose.yml
version: "3.3"
services:
    myservice:
      environment:
        MSG: i'm being cronjobbed, every minute!
      image: alpine
      container_name: myservice
      command: tail -f /dev/null

    cronjobber:
     image: docker:edge
     volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
     container_name: cronjobber
     command: >
          sh -c "
          echo '* * * * * docker exec myservice printenv | grep MSG' > /etc/crontabs/root
          && crond -f"
```

Comment: I was unable to get this to work using docker swarm. Getting `myservice unknown` errors.

Comment: There should be a warning about the high security impact mounting a docker socket has: https://www.lvh.io/posts/dont-expose-the-docker-socket-not-even-to-a-container.html

Answer (score 6):

I decided to use busybox, as it is one of the smallest images.

crond is executed in foreground (-f), logging is send to stderr (-d), I didn't choose to change the loglevel.
crontab file is copied to the default path: /var/spool/cron/crontabs

```
FROM busybox:1.33.1

# Usage: crond [-fbS] [-l N] [-d N] [-L LOGFILE] [-c DIR]
#
#   -f  Foreground
#   -b  Background (default)
#   -S  Log to syslog (default)
#   -l N    Set log level. Most verbose 0, default 8
#   -d N    Set log level, log to stderr
#   -L FILE Log to FILE
#   -c DIR  Cron dir. Default:/var/spool/cron/crontabs

COPY crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root

CMD [ "crond", "-f", "-d" ]
```

But output of the tasks apparently can't be seen in `docker logs`.

Comment: The `-d` parameter requires the log level as argument. You should change your `CMD` line to:

`CMD [ "crond", "-f", "-d", "8" ]`

Answer (score 6):

I occasionally tried to find a `docker`-friendly `cron` implementation. And this last time I tried, I've found a couple.

By `docker`-friendly I mean, "output of the tasks can be seen in `docker logs` w/o resorting to tricks."

The most promising I see at the moment is [`supercronic`](https://github.com/aptible/supercronic). It can be fed a crontab file, all while being `docker`-friendly. To make use of it:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  supercronic:
    build: .
    command: supercronic crontab
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.17
RUN set -x \
    && apk add --no-cache supercronic shadow \
    && useradd -m app
USER app
COPY crontab .
```

`crontab`:

```
* * * * * date
```

A [gist](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/427172d62edc9ac6596d5382365e78b5) with a bit more info.

Another good one is [`yacron`](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/66fc314d2e38395ff5778398c233e017), but it uses YAML.

[`ofelia`](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/d135bfabbe1b4798ad2fcfbca11a907c) can be used, but they seem to focus on running tasks in separate containers. Which is probably not a downside, but I'm not sure why I'd want to do that.

And there's also a number of traditional `cron` implementations: [`dcron`](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/b21d457de5025379c7657fb7b139267b), [`fcron`](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/ddbf1cd7226d54da7c7e868c3ba5ba12), [`cronie`](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/4d6391931c0b6802f93e4c3c1f418066). But they come with "no easy way to see output of the tasks."

Comment: A good alternative to my [answer indeed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37458519/6309).

Answer (score 5):

When you deploy your container on another host, just note that it won't start any processes automatically. You need to make sure that 'cron' service is running inside your container.
In our case, I am using Supervisord with other services to start cron service.

```
[program:misc]
command=/etc/init.d/cron restart
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/misc-cron.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/misc-cron.out.log
priority=998
```

Comment: I get an error in supervisor.log that the cron service stopped multiple times and entered a FATAL state. However cron seems to be running in top and executing cronjobs normally. Thanks for this!

Comment: Yes, same thing happened to me as well, but it works as normal, so don't need to bother.

Answer (score 5):

From above examples I created this combination:

Alpine Image & Edit Using Crontab in Nano (I hate vi)

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk update
RUN apk add curl nano

ENV EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano 

# start crond with log level 8 in foreground, output to stderr
CMD ["crond", "-f", "-d", "8"]

# Shell Access
# docker exec -it <CONTAINERID> /bin/sh

# Example Cron Entry
# crontab -e
# * * * * * echo hello > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
# DATE/TIME WILL BE IN UTC
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Setup a cron in parallel to a one-time job

Create a script file, say run.sh, with the job that is supposed to run periodically.

```
#!/bin/bash
timestamp=`date +%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S`
echo "System path is $PATH at $timestamp"
```

Save and exit.

#### Use Entrypoint instead of CMD

f you have multiple jobs to kick in during docker containerization, use the entrypoint file to run them all.

Entrypoint file is a script file that comes into action when a docker run command is issued. So, all the steps that we want to run can be put in this script file.

For instance, we have 2 jobs to run:

**Run once job**: echo “Docker container has been started”

**Run periodic job**: run.sh

#### Create entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start the run once job.
echo "Docker container has been started"

# Setup a cron schedule
echo "* * * * * /run.sh >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# This extra line makes it a valid cron" > scheduler.txt

crontab scheduler.txt
cron -f
```

Let’s understand the crontab that has been set up in the file

`* * * * *`: Cron schedule; the job must run every minute. You can update the schedule based on your requirement.

`/run.sh`: The path to the script file which is to be run periodically

`/var/log/cron.log`: The filename to save the output of the scheduled cron job.

`2>&1`: The error logs(if any) also will be redirected to the same output file used above.

**Note**: Do not forget to add an extra new line, as it makes it a valid cron.
`Scheduler.txt`: the complete cron setup will be redirected to a file.

#### Using System/User specific environment variables in cron

My actual cron job was expecting most of the arguments as the environment variables passed to the docker run command. But, with bash, I was not able to use any of the environment variables that belongs to the system or the docker container.

Then, this came up as a walkaround to this problem:

1. Add the following line in the entrypoint.sh

```
declare -p | grep -Ev 'BASHOPTS|BASH_VERSINFO|EUID|PPID|SHELLOPTS|UID' > /container.env
```

2. Update the cron setup and specify-

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
BASH_ENV=/container.env
```

At last, your `entrypoint.sh` should look like

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start the run once job.
echo "Docker container has been started"

declare -p | grep -Ev 'BASHOPTS|BASH_VERSINFO|EUID|PPID|SHELLOPTS|UID' > /container.env

# Setup a cron schedule
echo "SHELL=/bin/bash
BASH_ENV=/container.env
* * * * * /run.sh >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# This extra line makes it a valid cron" > scheduler.txt

crontab scheduler.txt
cron -f
```

#### Last but not the least: Create a Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Himanshu Gupta

# Install cron
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron

# Add files
ADD run.sh /run.sh
ADD entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
 
RUN chmod +x /run.sh /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```

That’s it. Build and run the Docker image!

Comment: @himanshuIIITian I tried this, the issue is that the script of the "run once job" is never returning and also the corn -f is not returning so... this is not working for me, any ideas? thanks

Comment: @DoronLevi - can you please share some logs to look into the issue? Or you can check the whole code from here - https://github.com/nehabhardwaj01/docker-cron

Comment: You don't need ENTRYPOINT to run multiple commands. And generally the description/solution seems too complex.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my `docker-compose` based solution:

```
  cron:
    image: alpine:3.10
    command: crond -f -d 8
    depends_on:
      - servicename
    volumes:
      - './conf/cron:/etc/crontabs/root:z'
    restart: unless-stopped
```

the lines with cron entries are on the `./conf/cron` file.

**Note:** this won't run commands that aren't in the `alpine` image.

Also, output of the tasks apparently won't appear in `docker logs`.

Answer (score 4):

This question have a lot of answers, but some are complicated and another has some drawbacks. I try to explain the problems and try to deliver a solution.

`cron-entrypoint.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# copy machine environment variables to cron environment
printenv | cat - /etc/crontab > temp && mv temp /etc/crontab

## validate cron file
crontab /etc/crontab

# cron service with SIGTERM support
service cron start
trap "service cron stop; exit" SIGINT SIGTERM

# just dump your logs to std output
tail -f  \
    /app/storage/logs/laravel.log \
    /var/log/cron.log \
    & wait $!
```

Problems solved

- environment variables are not available on cron environment (like env vars or kubernetes secrets)
- stop when crontab file is not valid
- stop gracefully cron jobs when machine receive an SIGTERM signal

For context, I use previous script on Kubernetes with Laravel app.

Comment: If I run `docker stop` with this setup, nothing happens, i.e. `service cron stop` doesn't get executed. If I run the latter manually from within the container, the `cron` process stops immediately instead of waiting for the cronjobs. cronjobs will still complete their run, so that may be fine. When they are done, the container does not stop either though. What am I missing?

Comment: Got it working now. I think the trap handler wasn't triggered, because I defined my entryscript as `CMD "/bin/sh" ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh` instead of `ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]`. That way, it got wrapped in another shell which didn't pass the signals through. I had to do some further steps to actually wait for running cronjobs to finish. Elaborating on your answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72735422/1665966).

Answer (score 3):

This code has successfully worked for me. I placed the script.sh file inside the project folder, and both the script.sh and main.py Docker files are located at the same directory level. I made the following modifications to the Docker file in order to execute the Cron-job within the Docker container.

Script.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
# script.sh

sleep 0
wget http://127.0.0.1:8081/v1.0/recommend/cronjob
```

Docker File

```
# Choose our version of Python
FROM python:3.11

# Set up a working directory
WORKDIR /opt/myapp
# Copy the code into the working directory
COPY . /opt/myapp
# Upgrade PIP
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
# Install requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8081

# Start both FastAPI and cron jobs
ADD script.sh /root/script.sh
RUN chmod 0644 /root/script.sh
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install cron
RUN crontab -l | { cat; echo "30 2 * * * bash /root/script.sh"; } | crontab -

# Tell uvicorn to start spin up our code, which will be running inside the 
container now
CMD ["bash", "-c", "cron && uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8081"]
```

Answer (score 2):

this line was the one that helped me run my pre-scheduled task.

```
ADD mycron/root /etc/cron.d/root

RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/root

RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/root

RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

CMD ( cron -f -l 8 & ) && apache2-foreground # <-- run cron
```

--> My project run inside: **FROM php:7.2-apache**

**But: if `cron` dies,** the container [keeps running](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/f17b2cefc6e673e979850d79b265f345).

Answer (score 2):

With multiple jobs and various dependencies like `zsh` and `curl`, this is a good approach while also combining the best practices from other answers. Bonus: This does NOT require you to set `+x` execution permissions on `myScript.sh`, which can be easy to miss in a new environment.

`cron.dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install \
  cron \
  zsh \
  curl;

# Setup multiple jobs with zsh and redirect outputs to docker logs
RUN (echo "\
* * * * * zsh -c 'echo "Hello World"' 1> /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2 \n\
* * * * * zsh /myScript.sh 1> /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2 \n\
") | crontab

# Run cron in forground, so docker knows the task is running
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

Integrate this with docker compose like so:

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
services:
  cron:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./cron.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./myScript.sh:/myScript.sh
```

Keep in mind that you need to `docker compose build cron` when you change contents of the `cron.dockerfile`, but changes to `myScript.sh` will be reflected right away as it's mounted in compose.

Answer (score 1):

When running on some trimmed down images that restrict root access, I had to add my user to the sudoers and run as `sudo cron`

```
FROM node:8.6.0
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron sudo

COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/my-cron
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/my-cron
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Allow node user to start cron daemon with sudo
RUN echo 'node ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/cron' >>/etc/sudoers

ENTRYPOINT sudo cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

Maybe that helps someone

**But: if `cron` dies,** the container [keeps running](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/f17b2cefc6e673e979850d79b265f345).

Comment: I believe the node image uses the node user; so maybe you needed to add permissions for that user

Answer (score 1):

So, my problem was the same. The fix was to change the command section in the `docker-compose.yml`.

**From**

command: crontab /etc/crontab && tail -f /etc/crontab

**To**

command: crontab /etc/crontab

command: tail -f /etc/crontab

The **problem** was the '&&' between the commands. After deleting this, it was all fine.

Comment: The second command overrides the first one. That is, having 2 command keys equals to having only the last one (the last one wins).

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on *gracefully* stopping the cronjobs when receiving `SIGTERM` or `SIGQUIT` signals (e.g. when running `docker stop`).

That's not too easy. By default, the cron process just got killed without paying attention to running cronjobs. I'm elaborating on [pablorsk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69255890/1665966):

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install cron procps \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy cronjobs file to the cron.d directory
COPY cronjobs /etc/cron.d/cronjobs

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cronjobs

# similarly prepare the default cronjob scripts
COPY run_cronjob.sh /root/run_cronjob.sh
RUN chmod +x /root/run_cronjob.sh
COPY run_cronjob_without_log.sh /root/run_cronjob_without_log.sh
RUN chmod +x /root/run_cronjob_without_log.sh

# Apply cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cronjobs

# to gain access to environment variables, we need this additional entrypoint script
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

# optionally, change received signal from SIGTERM TO SIGQUIT
#STOPSIGNAL SIGQUIT

# Run the command on container startup
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

`entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# make global environment variables available within crond, too
printenv | grep -v "no_proxy" >> /etc/environment

# SIGQUIT/SIGTERM-handler
term_handler() {
  echo 'stopping cron'
  service cron stop
  echo 'stopped'
  echo 'waiting'
  x=$(($(ps u -C run_cronjob.sh | wc -l)-1))
  xold=0
  while [ "$x" -gt 0 ]
  do
    if [ "$x" != "$xold" ]; then
      echo "Waiting for $x running cronjob(s):"
      ps u -C run_cronjob.sh
      xold=$x
      sleep 1
    fi
    x=$(($(ps u -C run_cronjob.sh | wc -l)-1))
  done
  echo 'done waiting'
  exit 143; # 128 + 15 -- SIGTERM
}

# cron service with SIGTERM and SIGQUIT support
service cron start
trap "term_handler" QUIT TERM

# endless loop
while true
do
  tail -f /dev/null & wait ${!}
done
```

`cronjobs`

```
* * * * * ./run_cronjob.sh cron1
*/2 * * * * ./run_cronjob.sh cron2
*/3 * * * * ./run_cronjob.sh cron3
```

Assuming you wrap all your cronjobs in a `run_cronjob.sh` script. That way, you can execute arbitrary code for which shutdown will wait gracefully.

`run_cronjobs.sh` (optional helper script to keep cronjob definitions clean)

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR_INCL="${BASH_SOURCE%/*}"
if [[ ! -d "$DIR_INCL" ]]; then DIR_INCL="$PWD"; fi
cd "$DIR_INCL"

# redirect all cronjob output to docker
./run_cronjob_without_log.sh "$@" > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```

`run_cronjob_without_log.sh`

```
your_actual_cronjob_src()
```

Btw, when receiving a `SIGKILL` the container still shut downs immediately. That way you can use a command like `docker-compose stop -t 60 cron-container` to wait 60s for cronjobs to finish gracefully, but still terminate them for sure after the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers require root access inside the container because 'cron' itself requests for UID 0.
To request root acces (e.g. via sudo) is against docker best practices.
I used https://github.com/gjcarneiro/yacron to manage scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the list of answers that you can also use this image:
https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/cronit/simple-cron

And use it as a basis to start cron jobs, using it like this:

```
FROM cronit/simple-cron # Inherit from the base image
#Set up all your dependencies 
COPY jobs.cron ./ # Copy your local config
```

Comment: Not a public image?

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, it is possible to run **cron** as a process  inside the container (under root user) alongside other processes , using `ENTRYPOINT` statement in Dockerfile with `start.sh` script what includes line `process cron start`. More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

```
#!/bin/bash

# copy environment variables for local use
env >> etc/environment

# start cron service
service cron start

# start other service
service other start
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image doesn't contain any daemon (so it's only the short-running script or process), you may also consider starting your cron from **outside**, by simply defining a LABEL with the cron information, plus the scheduler itself. This way, your default container state is "exited". If you have multiple scripts, this may result in a lower footprint on your system than having multiple parallel-running cron instances.

See: https://github.com/JaciBrunning/docker-cron-label

Example docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.8'

# Example application of the cron image
services:
  cron:
    image: jaci/cron-label:latest
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"

  hello:
    image: hello-world
    restart: "no"
    labels:
      - "cron.schedule=* * * * * "
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share a modification to the typical off of some of these other suggestions that I found more flexible. I wanted to enable changing the cron time with an environment variable and ended up adding an additional script that runs within my entrypoint.sh, but before the call to cron -f

```
*updatecron.sh*
#!/bin/sh
#remove old cron files
rm -rf /etc/cron.*/*
#create a new formatted cron definition
echo "$crondef [appname] >/proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2" >> /etc/cron.d/restart-cron
echo \ >> /etc/cron.d/restart-cron
chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/restart-cron
crontab /etc/cron.d/restart-cron
```

This removes any existing cron files, creates a new cronfile using an ENV variable of crondef, and then loads it.

Answer (score 0):

Our's was a nodejs application to be run as cron job and it was also dependent on environment variables.

The below solution worked for us.

Docker file:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:12.18.1
ENV NODE_ENV=production

COPY ["startup.sh", "./"]

# Removed steps to build the node js application

#--------------- Setup cron ------------------
# Install Cron
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install cron
 
# Run every day at 1AM
#/proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2 is used to redirect cron logs to standard output and standard error
RUN (crontab -l ; echo "0 1 * * * /usr/local/bin/node /app/dist/index.js  > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2") | crontab
    
#--------------- Start Cron ------------------
# Grant execution rights
RUN chmod 755 startup.sh
CMD ["./startup.sh"]
```

startup.sh:

```
!/bin/bash
echo "Copying env variables to /etc/environment so that it is available for cron jobs"
printenv >> /etc/environment
echo "Starting cron"
cron -f
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who wants to use a simple php-fpm image:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y cron\ 
...

# Copy your cronjob file
COPY /cron/cronjob /etc/cron.d/crontab
COPY /cron/log /var/log

# owner can read and write into the crontab, group and others can read it
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
# running our crontab using the binary from the package we installed
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

CMD cron && docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm
```

Not that this part is required if you want to use this Image in docker-compose.yml file : `&& docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm`

if not, I had an error : 502 bad gateway issue (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream) by nginx image.

I hope this can help someone