# Cron isn't running when I start my docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, cron, docker-compose

To preface, I have been referencing these two articles for help:

- [Run a cron job with Docker - Julien Boulay](https://www.ekito.fr/people/run-a-cron-job-with-docker/)
- [Running cron jobs inside a Docker container - Chris S.](http://www.anotherchris.net/posts/running-cron-jobs-inside-a-docker-container)

My goal is to have a cron job automatically start when I start my docker container. Currently, it doesn't automatically start, but I can manually go into my container and run `service cron start`, which starts the job, and it works correctly.

So the problem is: **How do I get my cron job to start automatically when my container starts up?**

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN chmod 0600 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN crontab -u root /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 5000/tcp

CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
CMD service cron start
```

*crontab*

```
* * * * * echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# Empty space
```

---

Though I wasn't able to get cron working in that particular container, I was able to create a standalone docker container specifically for cron, and was successful in getting it to run automatically.

As far as setup for the cron container, I followed the linked article, [Run a cron job with Docker - Julien Boulay](https://www.ekito.fr/people/run-a-cron-job-with-docker/), and was able to get it working.

Comment: Do you need cron to be running inside the container, or could you create a cron job on the host that will run this container at the desired time to do its work?

Comment: @R0MANARMY It needs to be running inside the container.

Comment: You've already seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container) ?

Comment: @R0MANARMY Yes, that question basically just outlines my first reference.

Comment: This may seem like a stupid question, but is your container running? I see you have 2 `CMD` directives at the end of your Dockerfile, I think the second one will overwrite the first. Assuming it does, `service cron start` should finish successfully, once the command finishes running, your container should shut down.

Comment: @R0MANARMY My container is running. It stays running too, until I run `docker-compose kill`.

Comment: Per [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd), there can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. I would suggest taking out the second one. It also looks like there are only a couple of other differences between your Dockerfile and the one in the other answer. I would try changing those one at a time to see if you can get it to run.

Answer (score 17):

What I'm doing is have the CMD call cron directly like this:

```bash
CMD /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

Before that I'm adding the crontab to the container and assigning it as the root crontab with the command:

```
RUN crontab /root/mycrontab
```

You don't need to call the crontab command on files that are located in `/etc/cron.d`, but you do need those files to have the correct syntax. Using your example, instead of this:

```
* * * * * echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

You should have this:

```
* * * * * root echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

On your crontab file. This only applies to crontab files located within `/etc/cron.d`, otherwise your crontab file syntax is correct and you use the `crontab` command to load it.

Starting from your example, I think you should modify your files like this:

Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN chmod 0600 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 5000/tcp

CMD /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

crontab

```
* * * * * root echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

Another alternative would be:

Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

ADD crontab /root/
RUN crontab /root/crontab
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 5000/tcp

CMD /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

crontab

```
* * * * * echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm having trouble following you. Do you mind editing your answer to display what my *Dockerfile* and *crontab* files would look like? Thanks!

Comment: I tried both versions of your answer, and it's still not working. Is there any additional information I can provide to better help?

Comment: I just tested it using the second version (removing the dotnet restore & build commands from the dockerfile) and cron works. Can you get inside the container and see if cron is running? (ex: `ps auxw|grep cron`)

Comment: So what I am doing is; `docker-compose build`, `docker-compose up -d`, then I am entering my container via `docker exec -it {container-id} bash`, then checking to see if cron is running by `service cron status`, which returns `cron is not running ... failed!`

Comment: I tried with the same commands, but for me `service cron status` returns `cron is running.`. I'm testing on an ubuntu box with 4.4.0.45-generic kernel. Are you testing on a Windows box?

Comment: I am running `Linux 4280056316a8 3.13.0-96-generic #143-Ubuntu`.

Comment: I just tested the solution on an Ubuntu box with ` 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64` kernel and it works there as well. What happens if you run `/usr/sbin/cron -f` from your container after you've launched it with `docker-compose up -d`?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It returns nothing. Cron is still not running, even after making my code reflect your recent answer change.

Answer (score 9):

We had a problem with **php-fpm** and docker where our cronjob tasks were not be executed. There were two problems we solved:

- We tried to copy a `crontab` file into the docker container by using `COPY config/custom-cron /etc/cron.d/custom-cron`. The problem is, that our *line endings* were in *windows* format. This did break our crontab file, because this line endings are not converted while copy that file into the container.
- The second problem was, that we tried to start the cron via `CMD ["cron", "-f"]` which did block the main `php-fpm` process. This results in a `502 Bad gateway` error when calling our web application.

---

Finaly we made it work by editing the crontab file manually while building the docker image instead of copy-pasting and using supervisord to have multiple tasks running inside docker. This should work on all supported operating systems.

#### dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1.16-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron supervisor

# Configure cron
RUN crontab -l | { cat; echo "* * * * * echo 'Hello world' >> /var/log/cron-test.log 2>&1"; } | crontab -

# Configure supervisor
COPY config/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

## supervisord.conf

```
[supervisord]
logfile = /dev/null
loglevel = info
pidfile = /var/run/supervisord.pid
nodaemon = true

[program:php-fpm]
command = php-fpm
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stdout_logfile = /dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 0
stderr_logfile = /dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 0

[program:cron]
command = cron -f
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stdout_logfile = /dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 0
stderr_logfile = /dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 0
```

Comment: THANKS A TON for pointing this out!
We noticed that our laravel scheduled jobs suddenly stopped working in a PROD application and has no clue why.
Turns out, the issue started after we deployed a docker container built on Windows. Previously we had only deployed containers built on Linux.
I just converted the crontab to UNIX format and was able to fix the issue, even when deployed from a Windows machine.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug in Debian based distributions which will cause cronjobs to fail because docker uses layered filesystem and cron doesn't start and says `NUMBER OF HARD LINKS > 1 (/etc/crontab)`.

The fix is simple, add `touch /etc/crontab /etc/cron.*/*` to the entrypoint of your container.

I have made a blog post explaining how to setup cron in a Docker container here : https://esc.sh/blog/cron-jobs-in-docker/

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. I had changed the domain name. Fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I found a fix to this on Debian and it solved my problem. Cron pam auth with uid was breaking my cron from being able to run.

```
RUN sed -i '/session    required     pam_loginuid.so/c\#session    required     pam_loginuid.so/' /etc/pam.d/cron
```