# Output of `tail -f` at the end of a docker CMD is not showing

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Using Docker for Mac 1.13.1 with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER docker@ekito.fr

#Install packages and clean downloaded packages in the lowest layer
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add crontab file in the cron directory
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Give execution rights on the cron job and create the log file to tail in the next layer
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron && touch /var/log/cron.log

# Run the command on container startup
CMD echo "starting" && echo "continuing" && (cron) && echo "tailing..."  && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

With a contab file of:

```
* * * * * root echo "Hello world `date`" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# Don't remove the empty line at the end of this file. It is required to run the cron job
```

When I build and run it with:

```
docker build -t docker-cron-master .
docker run docker-cron-master
```

I see the output:

```
docker run docker-cron-master
starting
continuing
tailing...
```

If I wait a minute the `tail -f` output doesn't appear. Yet if I login to the running container and tail the file I can see the contents:

```
$ docker exec -it 4eda6b1fc6ce bash
root@4eda6b1fc6ce:/# tail -f /var/log/cron.log
Hello world Fri May  5 09:53:01 UTC 2017
Hello world Fri May  5 09:54:01 UTC 2017
```

I tried adding another echo at the end of the CMD to see if it was only the last command who's STDOUT was being swallowed but that didn't help.

I have posted the code is on github at https://github.com/simbo1905/docker-cron

Thanks!

Comment: Run your main program (tail) using `exec` otherwise it won't receive Ctrl-C (quit) signals. That might also fix your problem.  `&& exec tail -f ..`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The docker filesystem uses copy-on-write with it's layered union fs. So when you write to a file that's part of the image, it will first make a copy of that file to the container filesystem which is a layer above all the image layers.

What that means is when you append a line to the /var/log/cron.log, it will get a new inode in the filesystem and the file that the `tail` command is following at is no longer the one you see when you `docker exec` into the container. You can solve that with a minor change to append "nothing" to the file which also modifies the last update timestamp which forces a copy-on-write:

```
CMD echo "starting" && echo "continuing" && (cron) \
 && echo "tailing..." && : >> /var/log/cron.log && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

I put together a gist that goes through this issue with a lot more detail over here: https://gist.github.com/sudo-bmitch/f91a943174d6aff5a57904485670a9eb

Comment: Can't wait to try this. It would explain a lot of weirds bugs I've been seeing.

Comment: I pulled the repo and tested before posting. My first suspicion was output buffering but `stdbuf` didn't fix it. Verified with `ls -il /var/log/cron.log` that it's getting a new inode after that first write.

Comment: This trick works for me. You can also use `touch /var/log/cron.log` instead of `: >> /var/log/cron.log`.

Comment: BMitch, sir, you are awesome!

Answer (score -2):

Try using a volume:

```
VOLUME /var/log/
```