# Running cron in a docker container on a windows host

Tags: docker, cron, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I am having some problems trying to make a container that runs a cronjob. I can see cron running using `top` in the container but it doesn't write to the log file as the below example attempts to. The file stays empty.

I have read answers to the same question here:

- [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)
- [Output of `tail -f` at the end of a docker CMD is not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802109/output-of-tail-f-at-the-end-of-a-docker-cmd-is-not-showing/43807880#43807880)

But I could not make any of the suggestions work. For example I used the dockerfile from here: https://github.com/Ekito/docker-cron/

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER docker@ekito.fr

# Add crontab file in the cron directory
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

#Install Cron
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install cron


# Run the command on container startup
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

crontab:

```
* * * * * root echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# Don't remove the empty line at the end of this file. It is required to run the cron job
```

It didn't work on my machine (windows 10). Apparently there seems to be a windows specific issue also reported by someone else: https://github.com/Ekito/docker-cron/issues/3

To test if it was just me doing something wrong I tried to do the same in a virtual machine running ubuntu (so an ubuntu host instead of my windows host) and that worked as expected. The log file is extended as expected.

So what can I do to try to make this work?

I tried writing to a mounted (bind) folder and making a volume to write to. Neither worked.

Answer (score 2):

rferalli's answer on the github issue did the trick for me:

"Had the same issue. Fixed it by changing line ending of the crontab file from CRLF to LF. Hope this helps!"

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. 
My workaround is to use Task Scheduler to run a .bat file that start a container instead

**Using Task Scheduler**: https://active-directory-wp.com/docs/Usage/How_to_add_a_cron_job_on_Windows.html

---

**hello.bat**

```
docker run hello-world
```

**TaskScheduler Action**

```
cmd /c hello.bat >> hello.log 2>&1
```

Hope this help :)