# See cron output via docker logs, without using an extra file

Tags: docker, logging

I am running "cron" in a docker container. 
Every day a script is executed. 
The output of this script I would like to see via "docker logs "

The process with PID 0 is the cron daemon in my container. Entrypoint starts cron in foreground:

```
/usr/sbin/crond -f
```

I understand, that I could redirect the script output to a file "path/to/logs"

```
07 2 * * * /data/docker/backup_webserver/backupscript.sh >> path/to/logs
```

and start the container as following to see the logs

```
"tail -f path/to/logs"
```

But then the file "path/to/logs" would grow during the runtime of the container. 
**Is there a possibility to log from crontab, directly to "docker logs" ?**

Comment: I've created a repo to work this out: https://github.com/tomsaleeba/alpine-cron-test. The answer seems to be to not add any extra redirects and it'll "just work", at least for my simple `echo` tests.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container/46220104#46220104) was the only effective approach in my situation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Change your cron file to below

```
07 2 * * * /data/docker/backup_webserver/backupscript.sh > /dev/stdout
```

This will make sure the logs go to the container output

Comment: This works on Alpine when started with `crond -l 2 -f`

Comment: Why does this work? I thought `/dev/stdout` would actually go to `/proc/self/fd/1` and for the process that cron starts, this won't be the `/proc/1/fd/1` file that docker monitors.

Comment: I don't think this will work because /dev/stdout is a link to STDOUT of the process accessing it. So by doing foo > /dev/stdout, you're saying "redirect my STDOUT to my STDOUT". Kinda doesn't do anything :-).

Comment: To add to my own comment, I think cron is gathering the output from the job and passing it to *its* stdout, which *is* the one that docker monitors.

Comment: @TomSaleeba, yes because the redirection is run the cron's process and that is why stdout is that of the cron only

Comment: `> /dev/stdout` is not a good option for production. I recommend to check mkfifo

Comment: this doesn't work for me. ```docker logs``` still returns nothing

Comment: Looks like it only works if crond is running in foreground.

Comment: if we use this answer's cron in side docker container should we also use  
`CMD cron -f && tail -f /var/log/cron.log` inside dockerfile ?

Comment: Thanks @TomSaleeba!! :) For me, this works:
`* * * * * something > /proc/1/fd/1`

Comment: Or even better: 
`* * * * * something > /proc/1/fd/1 2>&1`

Answer (score 24):

## **Alpine:** No need for redirection

***using the default cron utility (busybox)***

#### **Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.7

# Setting up crontab
COPY crontab /tmp/crontab
RUN cat /tmp/crontab > /etc/crontabs/root


CMD ["crond", "-f", "-l", "2"]
```

#### crontab

```
* * * * * echo "Crontab is working - watchdog 1"
```

## **Centos:**

### ***Redirection to  `/proc/1/fd/1` inside the crontab declaration line***

#### **Dockerfile**

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y install crontabs

ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab


CMD ["crond", "-n"]
```

#### crontab

```
* * * * * echo "Crontab is working - watchdog 1" > /proc/1/fd/1
```

[image]

Comment: I'm curious...  Why copy the crontab to /tmp then into /etc/crontabs/root?

Comment: Debian applies a patch to nullify the standard output, in a similar way as CentOS: https://salsa.debian.org/debian/cron/-/blob/master/debian/patches/fixes/Redirect-daemon-standard-streams-to-dev-null.patch I guess Alpine is the only one that does not apply this patch

Comment: And I suggest you to add ```2>/proc/1/fd/2``` to your answer for CentOS in order to catch errors sent to stderr

Comment: Could you please tell what does this mean: `using the default cron utility (busybox)` My ubuntu has a single busybox binary `/usr/bin/busybox`, which contains a set of applet. I need to use `busybox appletname` to access them. How can you refer to your `crond` inside a busybox without mentioning `busybox` in your command.

Comment: After testing alot of method finally your solution worked for me.

Comment: I had some problems switching from ubuntu->alpine b/c busybox has a stripped down /usr/bin/env.  Suddenly a bunch of #! lines stopped working when they have -S flags.  Fix: newer alpine:3.17.1, install coreutils and bash (skip ash).

Answer (score 9):

@mcfedr is correct, but it took me a while to understand it with it being a one-liner with variables and some extra code related to setting up cron.

This may be a little bit easier to read. It helped me to write it out explicitly.

```
# Create custom stdout and stderr named pipes
mkfifo /tmp/stdout /tmp/stderr
chmod 0666 /tmp/stdout /tmp/stderr

# Have the main Docker process tail the files to produce stdout and stderr 
# for the main process that Docker will actually show in docker logs.
tail -f /tmp/stdout &
tail -f /tmp/stderr >&2 &

# Run cron
cron -f
```

Then, write to those pipes in your cron:

```
* * * * * /run.sh > /tmp/stdout 2> /tmp/stderr
```

Comment: Thank you for this - I was able to grok the line-by-line breakdown - and it works 

Answer (score 3):

For Debian-based images, following `Dockerfile` works for me (note that `/etc/crontab` has a slightly different format, compared to user crontab files):

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y cron

RUN echo "* * * * * root echo 'Crontab is working - watchdog 1' > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2" > /etc/crontab

CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

Answer (score 2):

fifo is the way to go, it also useful because it allows cron tasks that are not running as root to write to the output.

I am using a CMD along these lines

```
ENV LOG_STREAM="/tmp/stdout"
CMD ["bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c", "mkfifo $$LOG_STREAM && chmod 777 $$LOG_STREAM && echo -e \"$$(env | sed 's/=\\(.*\\)/=\"\\1\"/')\n$$(cat /etc/cron.d/tasks)\" > /etc/cron.d/tasks && cron -f | tail -f $$LOG_STREAM"]
```

With the tasks in `/etc/cron.d/tasks`

```
* * * * */10 www-data echo hello >$LOG_STREAM 2>$LOG_STREAM
```

I also prepend the env at launch to `tasks` so it's visible to the tasks, as cron doesnt pass it though by itself. The `sed` is needed because crontab format requires env vars to be quoted - at least it requires empty vars to be quoted and fails to run tasks if you have an empty var without quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a FIFO.

```
mkfifo path/to/logs
```

> When processes exchanging data via the FIFO, the kernel passes all
>   data without writing it to the filesystem.  Thus, the FIFO special has
>   no contents on the filesystem; the filesystem entry merely serves a
>   reference point so that processes can access the pipe using a in the
>   filesystem.

[man fifo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)

Answer (score 0):

To get output (both stdout + stderr) of the command run by crond into docker logs, run your command this way:

```
command 2>/proc/1/fd/2 | tee -a /proc/1/fd/1
```

`2>/proc/1/fd/2` sends stderr output of `command` to output of docker container, without changing it from stderr to stdout.

`tee -a /proc/1/fd/1` sends stdout of `command` to output of docker container AND outputs it to standard output (as when you run `command` without any additions).

Why using `tee`? It makes whole string (cron job) more comfortable for debug: if you just copy it and paste to console (terminal) and execute, you would see output of `command` both on your console (terminal) and in docker container output (logs).