# Where can I find cron logs in Debian 11 by Docker

Tags: docker, cron, debian

I am using a Debian 11 container in which I have installed `cron` tool. I am using a custom Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:11-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade --yes && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends cron -y && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends python3 -y && \
    apt install --no-install-recommends python3-pip -y && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN service cron start
```

I am starting the cron service, it seems to be ok but no crontab schedule will be executed. Where can I find the cron logs? I have no `/var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your Dockerfile above is that you put the `service cron start` with the `RUN` directive. This directive specify that the command will only run on the Dockerfile build step, not when you are executing the built image. To understand the difference between `RUN`, `CMD`, `EXEC` directives of `docker`, refer to this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint-docker-commands/).

A very simple way of collecting log from `cron`, which makes use of the Docker's log collecting capability is to redirect the output of `cron` scripts to `stdout`. [Here](https://gist.github.com/mowings/59790ae930accef486bfb9a417e9d446) is a gist that contains the solution. Basically there is two part of the solution

- Specify the `cron` process as the entrypoint of the `docker` image.
- Make changes to the `crontab` file to redirect the output of cron jobs to `stdout` of the main `cron` process.

This gist is written for the Ubuntu image, so it should work or require little modification on Debian image. However, if your ultimate goal is to run `cron` in your image, I recommend using `alpine`. See [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60816190/13279274) for more information for this approach.

Comment: Cron service is running when I start my container. So crontab jobs should be executed. Unfortunately this is not happening so I have to check any cron errors or messages.

Comment: It is true that your crontab will be running when you start your container, but it will be in the background and not because of the `RUN service cron start` directive

My answer show you how to bring that `cron` service to be the main entrypoint of the image, and redirect the output of cronjobs to the main stdout so you can view it with Docker's log collecting facility