# Whenever gem logger in Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, logging, cron, whenever

I wonder how to get whenever gem task logs from Docker container.

```
  task my_task: :environment do
    Rails.logger.info 'start task'
    MyModel.call_some_method
  end
```

Task is running well, I can see it by the changes done to database table.
But for some reason I can't get any log information from container.

The only log I can fetch from container is:

```
# docker logs containerId
[write] crontab file updated
```

I tried to comment `:output` value in schedule.rb or use `set :output, '/dev/stdout'`.

But still no success.

Dockerfile:

```
...

ENTRYPOINT ["/rails/bin/docker-cron-entrypoint"]

CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

docker-cron-entrypoint file:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
bundle exec whenever --update-crontab
exec "${@}"
```

UPDATE:
Solved. In schedule.rb

```
set :output, '/proc/1/fd/1'
```

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395390/see-cron-output-via-docker-logs-without-using-an-extra-file It seems the correct answer may be different based on the image you are using. I never used this gem this way but seems you need to play with those `/proc/1/fd/1`, etc.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/javan/whenever/wiki/Output-redirection-aka-logging-your-cron-jobs