# Cron in Docker container parallel with Django

Tags: python, django, docker, cron

I am currently running a Django web application in a Docker compose setup on Rancher. Because I want the server to run Django management commands periodically I've setup a crontab for it.

```
* * * * * root /usr/local/bin/python /usr/src/app/manage.py updatesomething >> /usr/src/app/cron.log 2>&1
```

I am using the Dockerfile shown below and as you can see I've tried running the crontab standalone with `CMD ["cron", "-f"]`. This works fine and runs the command as it should. *The idea however is that it can run parallel and trigger management commands on the web app*. I've also verified that the crontab file is present.

The cron.log file remained empty for over 10 minutes so cron clearly is not doing its job here. Does anyone have a solution to running cron parallel in a `python:3` container? Supervisor is not really an option as I have a Python 3 codebase. And I couldn't yet get [Circus](https://github.com/circus-tent/circus) to work with the database in another container.

```
############################################################
# Dockerfile to run a Django-based web application
# Based on a Python 3 image
############################################################

# Set the base image to use to Python 3
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq --force-yes cron
COPY ./docker/crontab/updatesomething /etc/cron.d/updatesomething
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/updatesomething

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app /srv/logs
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN cron

# Copy application files
COPY . /usr/src/app/

# Port to expose
EXPOSE 8000

# Copy entrypoint script into the image
COPY docker_entrypoint.sh /docker_entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker_entrypoint.sh
CMD ["/docker_entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: You must start cron in `docker_entrypoint.sh`. It's possible to spin up an independent container for cron and another for the wsgi web server. `RUN` cannot start a deamon process such as `crond`.

Comment: See this question for details about running cron in docker. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container

Comment: @HåkenLid Ah thanks I overlooked the part that `RUN` does not actually run on the target machine and thus would not start up `cron`. I have some database issues left now but I guess I can figure those out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run management commands periodically, have a look at [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) and use [Celery beat](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html). You can run tasks that call the management commands on specific times, the same as you would do with cron. Django has a way to call management commands from within the code. You can run Celery and Celery beat from your docker-compose setup.

```
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.management import call_command

@shared_task
def management_command_task():
    call_command('my_command', 'foo', bar='baz')
```