# How to pass crontab command when running docker

Tags: docker

I want to run docker by `docker run` command and want to pass crontab command like bleow.

```
crontab -l | '{ /bin/cat; /bin/echo "*/5 * * * * <some command>"; }' | crontab -
```

The above command will create a cronscript which will run every 5 mins inside the new created docker container.

I dont need to supply this command when building image.
*This docker will be created when job is scheduled.

Comment: Docker containers are not full Linux VMs, so a typical docker container does not have a running `crond` to take your request as a VM could.  You either need to include a `cron` install in your `Dockerfile` or use some one else's cron-ready container.  You may also need to start `crond` which raises other issues about whether it is wise to run multiple processes in a docker container. Some examples and more warnings are in the answers to [How to Run a Cron Job Inside a Docker Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
docker run -it image /bin/bash -c "crontab -l | /bin/cat; /bin/echo \"*/5 * * * * <some command>\" |crontab - ; service cron restart"
```

Comment: +1 for using `bash -c` and for taking the time to properly escape quotes, as well as being the most correct answer to the question being asked

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cmd-default-command-or-options), you can indeed specify a command with `docker run`.

> `docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]`

One thing to note here as this will override any `CMD` instruction that is baked in the image, which may not be desired. If overriding is not an option, then you would have to EXEC into the container with `docker exec -it <CONTAINER_NAME> bash`, and run the command that way, as per Abe's answer.

So if the image you are running "does not" have a CMD instruction in the `Dockerfile`, you should be able to accomplish this with the following:

`docker run -it some/image /bin/bash -c "crontab -l | '{ /bin/cat; /bin/echo \"*/5 * * * * <some command>\" }' | crontab -"`

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to bash line command of your container and run the command, like this:

`docker exec -it <my container> /bin/bash`

and, you'll gain access to your container cli.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Can you help me complete command to used with `docker run`?