# Docker CMD loop

Tags: docker

I´m new on docker but i know that a docker container should have only one process. But is it possible to run a script inside of a docker container multiple times like by a cronjob?
For example I have a python script which manipulate my database. This process should be done every hour. For that i have created a container based on a file like that:

```
FROM python:slim
COPY ac.py ac.py
RUN pip install pymongo
CMD [ "python", "./ac.py" ]
```

If i load this container from my repository and start it on any environment the process is done only one time.
Is there any posibillity to start that like a cronjob (without use ubuntu image inside of my docker container)?

By the way I want to deploy this container in google cloud. Is there any cloud provider who provide a functionality like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)

Comment: no like i wrote, i don´t wants to use an ubuntu image.

Comment: But `python:slim` is based on debian, there you have cron jobs as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage docker swam and create a service that will have restart condition set to `any` and a delay between restarts set to `1h`.

```
docker service create --restart-condition any --restart-delay 1h myPythonImage:latest
```

See `docker service create` reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#options

Comment: is that doing the restart every hour or only one time after one hour?

Comment: it will run a new container based on the image after 1h delay from detecting previous service container is not running (detection is usually in couple seconds).