# Best way to run cron in docker container

Tags: linux, docker, cron, docker-compose

Suppose we have to run a script every 15 mins with tools that already exist in our app container (e.g. php, node, etc.) What is the best way to do this?

For example:

1. Run cron within the app container
2. Run cron as a separate container
3. Run cron on the host (using docker exec)

***UPDATES***

Most of the answers to this question seem to only address `SYSTEM crons` which are installed either in `/etc/cron.d/` or `/etc/crontab` on the Ubuntu 16.04 base image however I'm more interested in USER crons which normally reside in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` for ALL `users crons` or I believe in `/home/user/crontab(not too sure)`

I am running my container as a `non-root user` and need to be able to do `RUN crontab myCrontab` and have `myCrontab` under that `non-root user within my container` and NOT the usual system path listed earlier above.

Hope that's clearer and not identified as a duplicate of the other popular question.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I think the second option is generally the best. Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75353647/52499).