# How to use Crontab to execute shell scripts that require tty

Tags: cron, centos

I want to use a **Crontab** to execute a script at 8 o'clock every morning, but my script contains command `docker exec -it`. So returns following error"cannot enable tty mode on non tty input"

The solution I found was not use the `-t` parameter, But to interact with docker, I have to allocate **tty**.

Is there any way to make **Crontab** create a **tty** or other better timed execution method?

Edit: The parameters I need to pass to the docker are generated by the Host CentOS . Can I execute cron job inside docker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)

Comment: @rahoogan Thank you for your reply, I have two questions. 1.
Is there any difference between crontab -e and Add crontab file in the cron directory? 2. 
Do I need to create a new docker with an operating system to execute crontab?

Answer (score 0):

To replace **Crontab**, I used `while 1`.

Both `&` and `nohup` will be stop when execute command `docker exec -it`

[Screen](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/package/epics/extensions/iocConsole/screen.1.html) can solve this problem.