# Cron doesn't seem to run on Ubuntu Docker container

Tags: docker, cron, ubuntu-16.04

Relevant parts of Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install -y cron
RUN service cron start

ADD cronjob /etc/cron.d/gptswmm-cron
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/gptswmm-cron
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/gptswmm-cron
RUN cron
```

I check `ps -ef` output and cron isn't there. Whatever, I can spin it up manually after the fact with `cron` command and it shows up (just to check all my boxes, also do `service cron start`).

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 15:54 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash
root        41     0  0 15:59 ?        00:00:00 cron
root        65     0  0 16:02 ?        00:00:00 ps -ef
```

I do `crontab -l` and get the same as in my cronfile (which does have the empty line and the end too):

```
MAILTO=""
* * * * * root python /var/test/testcron.py >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

Python file simply creates (or appends to, if existing) a test file in the same directory (ensured same dir as script location), repeating the same word. As simple a test as you can get. (I originally had it echo-ing to log file, but did this as I'm more comfortable with what's going on in a python script than bash). Python file is owned by root with all permissions to owner.

Yet when I check where the text file should be, nothing. When I check `/var/log/cron.log`, it's empty.

When I manually call `python /var/test/testcron.py` it works and creates the output file.

So I get some system logging going, redoing the Dockerfile with this at the end:

```
RUN apt-get install -y rsyslog
```

Rebuild and spin up container. Start rsyslog first `rsyslogd`, then cron with `cron` and double-checking with `service start cron`.

Check `/var/log/syslog` and cron seems to be getting called, these basic two lines repeat every minute:

```
... CRON[48]: (root) CMD (python /var/test/testcron.py >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1^M)
... CRON[47]: (root) CMD (root python /var/test/testcron.py >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1^M)
```

I'm at a loss here. Been googling and searching for various solutions, but nothing so far has worked.

Comment: Try using absolute path to python binary. Also remove this part (2>&1^M) and maybe some errors will show up. Btw what is that "^M"? Tough to know what's going wrong here.

Comment: Ran it with python pointed at `/usr/bin/python` and w/o the `2>&1` stuff. Not sure which did it (I'll test and figure out, but my guess is the 2nd thing). The `^M` still gets appended at the end of the syslog, just looks like `.../cron.log^M)` now. However, I'm seeing the output file now. I'll report back shortly whether pointing it to python absolutely or the `2>&1` removal was what did it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I had remove the `2>&1` from the cron job:

```
* * * * * root python /var/test/testcron.py >> /var/log/cron.log
```

I had copied most of the procedure from https://www.ekito.fr/people/run-a-cron-job-with-docker/ and assumed maybe there's a wire getting crossed since his tutorial is trying to output to console.

All credit to @brthornbury in comment to original question. Posting as answer for visibility for anyone else who stumbles across this.