# Monolog stdout/stderr logs to current terminal process in Docker

Tags: symfony, docker, monolog

I have a PHP/Symfony app running in Docker which uses Monolog to log to stdout/stderr. This all works great, except when running Symfony console commands inside a container.

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        stdout:
            type: filter
            handler: stdout_unfiltered
            max_level: notice
            channels: ['!event']

        stdout_unfiltered:
            type: stream
            level: debug
            path: 'php://stdout'

        stderr:
            type: stream
            level: warning
            channels: ['!event']
            path: 'php://stderr'

        console:
            type: console
            channels: ['!console', '!doctrine', '!event']
            process_psr_3_messages: false
```

The problem is that whenever a command is executed, the "stdout", "stderr" and "console" handlers log to the current terminal process. This causes the console output to be messed up, and `docker logs` not to contain the log entries: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRris.png.

Would there be an easy way to always send the logging output to the php-fpm (or any worker) process?

Answer (score -1):

log to the file `/proc/1/fd/1` (or fd/2)

```yaml
monolog:
    handlers:
        ...
        stdout_unfiltered:
            type: stream
            level: debug
            path: '/proc/1/fd/1'
        stderr:
            type: stream
            level: warning
            channels: ['!event']
            path: '/proc/1/fd/2'
        ...
```

Maybe you can check where this point to and redirect there (`docker exec aContainer ls -l /proc/1/fd/2`), but this could change depending on the container start.

Not sure if it is ideal, but it works (when symfony has write permisison for /proc/1/fd/*).

Comment: Just found out I am not the first with the idea of redirecting to `/proc/1/fd/1`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46220104/4124767