# How to write docker cron logs to stdout/stderr

Tags: docker, cron, stdout

I have docker where cron is ran using
`CMD ["cron","-f"]` command. This writes the output to the cron log file.

Is there any way to redirect these logs to the console.

My Base Image looks like

```dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN ls

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-12-jre

RUN apt-get -y install cron wget unzip



RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
    && apt-get update -qqy \
    && apt-get -qqy install google-chrome-stable \
    && rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/* \
    && sed -i 's/"$HERE\/chrome"/"$HERE\/chrome" --no-sandbox/g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome


ARG CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=76.0.3809.68
RUN wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && rm -rf /opt/chromedriver \
    && unzip /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt \
    && rm /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && mv /opt/chromedriver /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && chmod 755 /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && ln -fs /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION /usr/bin/chromedriver

COPY tests-cron /etc/cron.d/tests-cron
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/tests-cron
WORKDIR /etc/cron.d
RUN ls
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/tests-cron

RUN touch /var/log/cron.log



WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir pricetest

COPY --from=maven-container /app/ pricetest/
RUN cp /usr/bin/chromedriver ./pricetest

WORKDIR /app/pricetest
ENV SHELL=/bin/bash

CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

PS: I am still work in progress on this project. So I havent optimized the docker build.

And the cronfile ( `tests-cron` )  I am contains

```dockerfile
* * * * * root echo "Hello world"
```

Base image used: `ubuntu:latest`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to redirect logs to console, All you need to change the entry point of your Dockerfile. Here is the working example base on alpine which runs a cronjob every minute with output.

### Alpine image

CMD flags

```
-f  Foreground
-L FILE Log to FILE
```

Dockerfile

```dockerfile
FROM alpine:latest
RUN echo "* * * * * echo hello" | crontab - 
CMD ["crond","-f", "-L", "/dev/stdout"]
```

[image]

Another thing, Please always share your base image so it's easy to understand the context of the issue.

### Ubuntu image

The workaround in ubuntu is to replace the `CMD` a bit, but I will not recommend this approach as the cron as cron will not be the parent process of container. You can read more about this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container) and [here](https://github.com/Ekito/docker-cron)

If you want to optimization then use alpine the future image of docker container and here is the difference in the size of these two image.

> Alpine is just 5MB where Ubuntu is 91MB

[image]

Here is the working example of cron with output using base image Ubuntu

```dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update &&  apt-get -y install cron
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
RUN (crontab -l ; echo "* * * * * echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log") | crontab
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

Comment: I have updated the question with my docker file info and base image @adiii

Comment: Will this ubuntu version write the o/p to stdout @adii

Comment: o/p? yes, this version writes log to stdout. you can try this simple example will work the same as alpine .

Comment: Ubuntu version will create I/O operations and the log will increase in size as long as the container is running.

Comment: @Terel you can set log rotation in the docker run command or docker-compose

Comment: In my case using cron instead of cron -f solve the problem.