# Cron job won't run inside Docker container

Tags: docker, cron

I am trying to schedule a task to run inside my container, but can't get cron to execute anything.

I've followed both [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container) and https://serverfault.com/questions/924779/docker-cron-not-working with no success. Simply nothing happens when I start up my container.

I have made a simple container:

```
test/
    Dockerfile
    hello-cron
```

Contents of `Dockerfile`:

```sh
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron

COPY hello-cron /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

and `hello-cron`:

```sh
* * * * * root echo "Hello World" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

I build my container: `docker build -t cron-test .` and run it `docker run -t -i cron-test`.

There is no console output. I have also tried to enter bash in the image to check the contents of the log-file and whether or not the `hello-cron` file is actually added to the crontab:

```
docker exec -it <image-id> bash
```

and `cat /var/log/cron.log` yields nothing, while the `hello-cron` file is located at `/etc/cron.d/hello-cron`.

I know this seems like a duplicate, but none of the accepted solutions I have seen solves this issue.

Comment: Is your cronjob in `crontab -l` ?

Comment: Did you fix this without using alpine?  I cannot use alpine for my job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will suggest using alpine instead of ubuntu just for the sake of cron.

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN echo "* * * * * echo hello;exit 0" | crontab - 
CMD ["crond","-f"]
```

you can explore more option

```
    -c  Crontab directory
    -u  User
    -l  List crontab
    -e  Edit crontab
    -r  Delete crontab
    FILE    Replace crontab by FILE ('-': stdin)
```

Also with alpine you do not need to `make container good for no thing` with `CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log` like you add in ubuntu base image.

When you use CMD like `CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log` , cron is no more the root process of the container and the container will restart or suppose to stop if cron is down.

using `CMD ["crond","-f"]` you will able to see logs in the console if you run the container in the foreground  or you can checks logs latter.

**Bonus:**

You got working docker container for cronjob in just **5.58MB**