# unable to run R script in crontab in docker container

Tags: r, docker, cron, cron-task

I'm trying to run a R script inside docker container. Here is the example.

My working directory is like below.

```
myRDocker
  -dockerfile
  -scripts
     -save_iris.R
```

In the directory `myRDocker`, there is a `dockerfile` and a directory `scripts`, which contains a R script `save_iris.R`

My R script `save_iris.R` is like below:

```
write.csv(iris, '/data/iris.csv')
```

My dockerfile is like below:

```
# Install R version 3.6
FROM r-base:3.6.0

#install crontab
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron

RUN mkdir /data
COPY /scripts  /scripts
```

I went to my directory `myRDocker` and build docker image

```
docker build -t baser .
```

I run the docker container in bash.

```
docker run -it baser bash
```

After I get into the container, I did:

```
crontab -e
```

then add this line, then save

```
* * * * * Rscript /scripts/save_iris.R
```

It should save the file to the folder `/data` every min. However, I never found any file in the data folder inside the container.

My question is:

1. what did I do wrong in the above procedure? I feel like I might be missing something.... but could not figure out why...
2. what should I do if I want to run the scheduled cron task whenever container start. (something like put the cron task in a file, and run when container start....)

Comment: Maybe list the full path to "RScript"  under crontab? What exactly do you want to run in the crontab? It seems inefficient to schedule saving iris? Do you want to run the docker file instead?

Comment: You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why you are not starting the cronjob on container run time, instead of running after container start? Also, I do not think the crontab process will run in your case as your container is not doing any thing.

Try this, which will start `cron` on container run time and will also tail logs of cron job. but keep in mind your main process in this case is `tail -f /var/log/cron.log` not the cron process.

```
 FROM r-base:3.6.0

 RUN apt-get update &&  apt-get -y install cron

 RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
 COPY hello.r /hello.r
 RUN (crontab -l ; echo "* * * * * Rscript /hello.r  >> /var/log/cron.log") | crontab

# Run the command on container startup
 CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

So you will get the Rscript console logs to Container stdout.

hello.r

```
print("Hello World from R")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you help!  I tried to put `RUN cron` in the dockerfile and it did not work.  Your `CMD cron` works.  why  `RUN cron` does not work?

Comment: `RUN cron` only run at **build time**, so you need some thing that run at **run time**

Comment: In the case ,  `CMD cron` or `CMD /etc/init.d/cron start` does not seem to start cron at runtime.   I need to get into container in bash and do `/etc/init.d/cron start` ,  then cron start.  Do you know why? @Adiii

Comment: `CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log` this should work as i test it

Comment: Sorry. I mean in my case.   If you take the dockerfile in the post and add the cmd line ‘cmd /etc/init.d/cron start’ Build the image,run container in bash.  I checked.  Cron is not started

Comment: The docker `CMD` keep the process running in the foreground so I think `init.d` push process to background  but I am not sure. use the suggested one.

Comment: In bash, ‘cmd /etc/init.d/cron start ‘will start cron.  What should I put behind cmd in my dockfile?  I tried ‘cmd cron’. Not working.  I don’t need the log

Comment: `tail -f /var/log/cron.log`

Comment: sorry, just take a look at my dockerfile in the pos, ignore the copying data and scripts,   what I need to put for CMD  line? could you try that file?  I do not need to log.  I'm confused. do I have to have log? @Adiii

Comment: If not need log, remove the tail command and if there is other issue you can ask another question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58309045/how-to-start-cron-when-starting-a-rbase-docker-container   I opened another question. Hope it's clearer. @Adiii