# how to start cron when starting a Rbase docker container

Tags: r, docker, cron

I'm trying to build a docker container which runs R and cron. What I need is make cron run automatically when I start the container.

My dockerfile is like below:

```
# Install R version 3.6
FROM r-base:3.6.0

#install crontab
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron

# also tried CMD /etc/init.d/cron start
CMD cron
```

Then I built the image and run container in bash.
I checked the status of cron:

```
/etc/init.d/cron status
```

I got the cron status like below:

```
[FAIL] cron is not running ... failed!
```

I was able to start the cron by starting cron mannually:

```
/etc/init.d/cron start
```

My question is how I should modify my dockerfile (line `CMD`), so that when docker container start, cron start automatically?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What happens when you try `CMD /etc/init.d/cron start`?

Comment: same thing as CMD cron.   When I get into container in bash and check the status. cron is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMD /etc/init.d/cron start` will start cron in the background so your container will die as soon as it created.

In the second option, add `-f`

```
# Install R version 3.6
FROM r-base:3.6.0

#install crontab
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron

# also tried CMD /etc/init.d/cron start
CMD [ "cron", "-f" ]
```

So it will keep your container running.

```
-f
Stay in foreground mode, don't daemonize.
```

But you will not able to see the cron using `/etc/init.d/cron status`. use below dokcerfile.

```
FROM r-base:3.6.0
RUN apt-get update &&  apt-get -y install cron
RUN apt-get install procps -y
CMD ["cron" ,"-f"]
```

and then run

```
docker exec -it <your_container_id> bash -c "ps -aux"
```

You will see that the cron is running.

Comment: thanks.  I just tried. I did not see cron running.   Have you tried your solution? @Adiii

Comment: Yes, did you check with `ps - aux`?

Comment: Also build image with out cache and fresh image

Comment: sorry, I'm new to docker.  what do you mean 'build image with out cache and fresh image'? could you give a example like docker build ...........

Comment: Just add - - no-cache

Comment: no luck.  not working for me.  here is what I got.   `USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   6848  3648 pts/0    Ss   18:41   0:00 bash
root         6  0.0  0.0   8592  3060 pts/0    R+   18:43   0:00 ps -aux`

Comment: How you run the container? And how you run ps?

Comment: `docker run -it <container name> bash` then I'm in container.  I did `ps -aux`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200621/discussion-between-adiii-and-zesla).

Comment: Mmh, I guess this is not possible since you're defining a docker image. Would it be possible to enable cron using a docker-compose.yml? For the time being, whenever I start a container, I log in into it and run the command manually to enable it.