# Docker cron job

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cron

I need to schedule some cron jobs in docker/kubernetes environment, which will make some external service calls using `curl` commands. I was trying to use plain alpine:3.6 image but it doesn't have `curl`.

Any suggestion what base image will be good for this purpose? Also, it will be helpful if there are some examples.

Comment: There is a list of images here: 
https://hub.docker.com/r/curlimages/curl

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)

Comment: You can also run a [Kubernetes CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) without specifically running cron in a container.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare your own docker image which will includes packages you need or just use something like this https://github.com/aylei/kubectl-debug

Answer (score 1):

I am able to run curl as cronjob job using alpine image as

```
FROM alpine:3.6

RUN apk --no-cache add curl bash
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata

ENV TZ=Asia/Kolkata
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ /etc/timezone

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/cron \
    && touch /var/log/cron/cron.log \
    && mkdir -m 0644 -p /etc/cron.d

ADD curlurl /etc/crontabs/root
CMD bash -c "crond -L /var/log/cron/cron.log && tail -F /var/log/cron/cron.log"

#ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

Where curlurl is having simple curl command as cron job

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees >> /var/log/cron/cron.log
# Leave one blank line below or cron will fail
```

This is working fine . But now I have tried to make alpine base image with push in private repo to avoid downloading every time. But it stopped working. How can i debug why cron job is not running anymore. Below is the way I have used.

BaseImage

```
FROM alpine:3.6

RUN apk --no-cache add curl bash
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata

ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

Docker for curl

```
FROM my/alpine:3.6

ENV TZ=Asia/Kolkata
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ /etc/timezone

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/cron \
    && touch /var/log/cron/cron.log \
    && mkdir -m 0644 -p /etc/cron.d

ADD curlurl /etc/crontabs/root
CMD bash -c "crond -L /var/log/cron/cron.log && tail -F /var/log/cron/cron.log"
```

After making it like this I am not able to get any cron output . Any suggestion on how can I debug it.