# Dockerizin a python cronjob

Tags: python, docker, cron, dockerfile, python-3.7

I have a python script which should run with python3. Now I have a requirement to run it as a cronjob. And then containerizing the whole package. Hence when installed, docker image should setup the cronjobs and run the python script in the docker.

I tried to execute the following, the build was successful and running it doesn't five any errors too. But it's not working.

What's the issue here?

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask
waitress
```

***app.py***

```
from datetime import datetime

print("\nThis is the cronjob running...:" , str(datetime.now()),"\n")
```

***Dockerfile***

```
FROM python:3-alpine

ENV PROJ_DIR="/app"
ENV CRON_SPEC="* * * * *"
ENV LOG_FILE="${PROJ_DIR}/app.log"

WORKDIR ${PROJ_DIR}

COPY . ${PROJ_DIR}

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD echo "${CRON_SPEC} python ${PROJ_DIR}/app.py >> ${LOG_FILE} 2>&1" > ${PROJ_DIR}/crontab

CMD crontab ${PROJ_DIR}/crontab

CMD crontab -l

CMD cron && tail -f ${LOG_FILE}
```

Comment: When you say "it's not working", what does or doesn't happen?  How have you debugged this; have you looked at the contents of the filesystem?  (Docker only runs the last `CMD` when the container starts up.)

Comment: I would recommend Airflow instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, only the last `CMD` will be executed. You have to run your `shell` commands with `RUN`.

Here a working example of your `Dockerfile` with the required adjustments:

```
FROM python:3-alpine

ENV PROJ_DIR="/app"
ENV LOG_FILE="${PROJ_DIR}/app.log"
ENV CRON_SPEC="* * * * *" 

WORKDIR ${PROJ_DIR}

COPY . ${PROJ_DIR}

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN echo "${CRON_SPEC} python ${PROJ_DIR}/app.py >> ${LOG_FILE} 2>&1" > ${PROJ_DIR}/crontab
RUN touch ${LOG_FILE} # Needed for the tail
RUN crontab ${PROJ_DIR}/crontab
RUN crontab -l
CMD crond  && tail -f ${LOG_FILE} #crond runs per default in the background
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: yes it works now, i can see the docker running (docker ps). But now the problem is how to check the logs, to see the output of the, I ran docker logs -f <container_id>, but id doesn't print the expected output. I wonder whether the python is not running. Is there a way to check the issue here?

Comment: How long did you wait? The cronjob with `* * * * *` is running every minute. I've checked also locally and I've got some logs.

Comment: Thank you @CLNRMN, It works in the mac, the log shows the intended print. But when I ran the same Docker in the AWS Linux machine, it doesn't give any output. Is there a way to debug or any idea what could have gone wrong.

Comment: @KTB: I believe you need to install `cron` on the linux machine first. Check this if it could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container