# Host os: Windows10; Docker guest os: Centos:latest; is it possible to do systemd on this setup?

Tags: docker, centos, systemd

On Windows10 host creating the container based on centos:latest image:

```
# NB! the backticks is just PowerShell syntax to split long commands
docker run  --name='my_container' `
            --detach `
            --tty `
            centos `
            /usr/sbin/init
```

Then opening the container shell:

```
docker exec -it `
        my_container `
        /bin/bash
```

and running systemd:

```
# systemd
bash: systemd: command not found
```

Based on https://hub.docker.com/_/centos and other Google-ing results then the issue is that I should mount the host cgroup/systemd? Or am I misunderstanding something?

So this is not doable on Windows10 host?

Comment: You probably shouldn't run systemd in Docker in any case: it tries to do a _lot_ of things that are inappropriate for a container.  Can you avoid systemd and just run the single thing your container is trying to do as a foreground process?

Comment: @DavidMaze, hi&thanks for replying. The initial thing I am trying to solve is to run cron service to schedule stuff in the container. Any other methods to achieve that?

Comment: Try to see if this works for your purposes > https://stackoverflow.com/a/37458519/1535270. If you really need to have a process manager, you should give a try to the following recommendations > https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Comment: I'd start by reading questions like [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37458287/10008173).  It's okay and normal to have multiple containers in an application, so have a separate container to run scheduled tasks.

Comment: abestrad and @DavidMaze thank you for your answers. It seems you are referencing the same article and yes it works with Ubuntu as guest. But the question is about CentOS quest. I don't seem to get cron working on that one, not able to start the service due to missing service manager.

Comment: You don't typically "start a service" in Docker.  As the answers to that linked question suggest, you run things like cron daemons as the single foreground process in their respective containers.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks. Any hints/links "cron daemons as the single foreground process" how would I do this?