# Run a bash script as cron job in Docker container

Tags: bash, docker, cron

I would like to run a bash script periodically inside a Docker container (my work is based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37458519/6240756)

Here is my script `hello.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

Here is the cron file `hello-cron`:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * /app/hello.sh
# Empty line
```

And here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron

# Add backup script
COPY hello.sh /app/
RUN chmod +x /app/hello.sh

# Configure the cron
# Copy file to the cron.d directory
COPY hello-cron /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Apply cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Start the cron
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

I build and run the container but nothing happens. I should see "Hello world" displayed every minutes.
If I replace the call to the script in the cron file by directly `echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1`  it works, I see "Hello world" every minutes

What am I doing wrong?

*EDIT*

And the Docker commands:

```
docker build -t hello-cron .
docker run -t -i hello-cron
```

Comment: Can you put your `docker run` command, please?

Comment: @mulg0r see the edited post

Comment: Unrelated to this issue, but `cron` already knows about files in `/etc/cron.d`; you don't need to install them with the `crontab` command. Files in this directory do require an extra field (the username), so `* * * * * * root /app/hello.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

#### About your concrete question

The problem is that you're launching your docker with `-t -i`, and what you want is a background execution and check it interactively.

Try with:

```
docker run -d --name mycontainer hello-cron 
docker logs -f mycontainer
```

#### Best practices

If you are going to execute something periodically, consider if it should be in healthcheck definition, where you can set period and other variables.

Second, note that your cron.log is not mounted, so, you'd lose this info if docker restart.

Comment: @larsks, I've checked what I say. If he does it he gets the logs.

Comment: Eh, you may be right. It turns out I can't reproduce the problem in any case :)

Comment: Maybe we have different docker or OS versions. Mine are docker 19.03.8, ubuntu 20.04. Anyway I hope my answer helps him. It looks he and me have same versions because we both can reproduce it :)