# Can I run a cronjob in a MySQL docker container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

is it possible to run a cronjob to execute a python script in a MySQL docker conatiner?
Or should I create an Ubuntu docker container and install MySQL there?

Comment: yeah, make your own dockerfile which uses the mysql image you want then (install cron if not installed), ADD your script to the fs, run a cmd to apply the crontab.

Comment: which cmd is that to set cron? @LawrenceCherone

Comment: summing like: `CMD crontab -l | { cat; echo "* * * * * /path/to/your/file.py"; } | crontab -` though you could also write directly to one of `/etc/cron.d/*` files

Comment: This answer may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container

Answer (score 0):

You can run a python script in your MySQL Docker Container. In order to do that you have to install crontab and python client in order to execute the script. It will look something like this:

```
FROM mysql:latest

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y cron python 

COPY ./YOUR_SCRIPT.py /YOUR_SCRIPT.py

RUN chmod +x /YOUR_SCRIPT.py #MAKE SCRIPT EXECUTABLE

RUN crontab -l | { cat; echo "* * * * * /YOUR_SCRIPT.py"; } | crontab -

ENTRYPOINT ["/YOUR_SCRIPT.py"]
```