# How to run cron and web application in same container?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, cron, dockerfile

I am new to docker. Hardly I have containerized my php application to run it in the web interface. But I have some cron to run with it. I learnt how to create separate cron image and run it from  [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container). But my use case is different. **I need to use the php files from my php application container** which seems not possible from my way. I tried creating the docker-compose.yml as follow to see if it would work

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
    version: "3"
    
    services:
        app:
          build:
            context: ./docker/php
    container_name: 'app'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
       - "80:80"
       - "443:443"
    links:
       - db
    volumes:
       - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT-./src}:/var/www/html
       - ${PHP_INI-./docker/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
       - ${VHOSTS_DIR-./docker/apache2/vhosts}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
       - ${LOG_DIR-./docker/logs/apache2}:/var/log/apache2
    extra_hosts:
       - "test.local:127.0.0.1"
    hostname: cloudservice.local
    domainname: local
    #entrypoint: sh /var/www/html/cron.sh
```

As I have commented entry point here and if I do docker-compose up, everything works perfectly fine, My Dockerfile is as under

**Dockerfile:**

```
    FROM php:7.2.27-apache
    
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install -y cron
    RUN apt-get -y update --fix-missing
    RUN apt-get upgrade -y
    
    # Install useful tools
    RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils nano wget dialog
    
    # Install important libraries
    RUN apt-get -y install --fix-missing apt-utils build-essential git curl libcurl4 libcurl4-openssl-dev zip
    
    # Composer
    RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
    
    # Install xdebug
    #RUN pecl install xdebug-2.5.0
    #RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
    
    # Other PHP7 Extensions
    
    RUN apt-get -y install libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3-0 default-mysql-client
    RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql 
    RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_sqlite
    RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
    
    RUN docker-php-ext-install curl
    RUN docker-php-ext-install tokenizer
    RUN docker-php-ext-install json
    
    RUN apt-get -y install zlib1g-dev
    RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
    
    RUN apt-get -y install libicu-dev
    RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl
    
    RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring
    
    RUN apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev
    RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ 
    RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
    
    RUN pecl install redis-5.1.1 \
        && docker-php-ext-enable redis
    
    # Enable apache modules
    RUN a2enmod rewrite headers
```

My cron.sh file is as under

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Ensure the log file exists
touch /var/www/html/logs/crontab.log

# Ensure permission on the command
chmod a+x /var/www/html/cron-local/hn-shc-rapid-daily.sh

# Added a cronjob in a new crontab
echo "* * * * * bash /var/www/html/cron-local/hn-shc-rapid-daily.sh >> /var/www/html/logs/crontab.log 2>&1" > /etc/crontab

# Registering the new crontab
crontab /etc/crontab

# Starting the cron
/usr/sbin/service cron start

# Displaying logs
# Useful when executing docker-compose logs mycron
tail -f /var/www/html/logs/crontab.log
```

But with the entry point commented, i cannot run cron. If i don't comment entrypoint, then cron runs, my web application doesn't. Is there any possibility to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the docker file i added the following code after removing

*RUN a2enmod rewrite headers*

```
    # Copy hello-cron file to the cron.d directory
    COPY hello-cron /etc/cron.d/hello-cron #just any name

    # Give execution rights on the cron job
    RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

    # Apply cron job
    RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

    # Create the log file to be able to run tail
    RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

    # Enable apache modules
    RUN a2enmod rewrite headers
    
    CMD cron && /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

and cron.sh was changed to

```
    * * * * * echo "hello world" >> /var/www/html/logs/crontab.log 2>&1
```

This worked for me. I need not have to add entry neither on docker-compose nor on docker file, but I guess entry also would work.
I don't know if this is the right way to do. If anyone would give me more advance idea, I would be happy to give it a try.
Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same issue!! can you plz post your yml, dockerfile and cron.sh file altogether with their location, I know it's a lot to ask but I think u really can help !!.

Comment: Its already posted here or you can send me the live editor link and i will paste everything there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if you specify the entry point in the docker-compose file without "sh" in front of it. Remember that declaring a new entrypoint in the docker-compose file overwrites the entrypoint in the dockerfile. [Link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint)

I would advise you to create your own Entrypoint Script which will execute your crons in the container `CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]`

Example:

Create an file and named "entrypoint.sh" or whatever and save it in the same folder where your Dockerfile is located. In this file push your Content from your  cron.sh.

```
RUN apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ 
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

RUN pecl install redis-5.1.1 \
        && docker-php-ext-enable redis
    
# Enable apache modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

COPY entrypoint.sh /
    
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

But you could also just add your cron directly in the docker file.

```
...
# Enable apache modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

COPY your-cron.cron /
    
RUN crontab /your-cron.cron 
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but i don 't know how to that. But I tried adding CMD sh /var/www/html/cron.sh && /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND at the end of dockerfile yet only cron is running

Comment: yeah, I did a little tweak in  you answer and I was able to make it work. thanks a lot

Comment: Can you explain me what you had to change?

Comment: I have posted my answer below.