# How I can run cron in my docker container

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I spent almost a week Google looking for a solution to start cron job in my container, here is my Dockerfile if anybody can help please
I tried `CMD["cron", "-f"]` also but no luck:

```
 FROM php:7.2-apache
 WORKDIR /var/www/html/

 Linux Library
 RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
 libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
 libicu-dev \
 libmariadb-dev \
 unzip zip \
 zlib1g-dev \
 libpng-dev \
 libjpeg-dev \
 libfreetype6-dev \
 libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
 libpng-dev \
 curl \
 cron

 RUN apt-get clean

 RUN docker-php-ext-install zip mysqli pdo pdo_mysql gd curl

 RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

 RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
 RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

 RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install- 
 dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

 ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/html/public
 RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' 
 /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
 RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' 
 /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

 RUN a2enmod rewrite

 COPY . /var/www/html/

 RUN composer install --no-interaction
 # EXPOSE 80

 RUN echo "* * * * * php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 
 2>&1" >> /etc/crontab

 COPY package.json package-lock.json /var/www/html/
 RUN npm install
 RUN npm run prod
 RUN service cron start
```

can any body fix my docker file please or suggest a way

Expecting the cron job to work,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64183620/how-to-run-cron-and-web-application-in-same-container

Comment: Why would you run a cronjob inside a container running a webserver? It would be better to separate the responsibility, but still based on the same container.

Comment: Remove `RUN service cron start` for starters, `CMD /usr/sbin/cron -f` should be enough to ensure the container stays alive and cron is running. Is that causing any errors or is it just not doing anything? Maybe also drop the `>> /dev/null` bit in your cron file to see output