# How to run cron with nginx service together?

Tags: image, docker, nginx, cron

I created a docker image to run crontab based on the official nginx image.

```
FROM nginx

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron

CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

If I don't set the last line `CMD ["cron", "-f"]`, the crontab service can't start after running it as a container. But if I set it, nginx can't start.

```
docker build -t some-content-nginx .
docker run --name some-nginx -d -p 8080:80 some-content-nginx
(Nginx isn't running)
```

**How to start these 2 services together?**

Comment: You only run one process per container, and so you'd run a separate cron container (for example, [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)).  Is there a specific reason you're trying to run them in the same container?

Comment: Because I want to use `crontab` to monitor logrotate for nginx logs in one container. In other container it can't get nginx's pid.

Comment: You might consider the default `nginx` image setting that writes logs to the `docker logs` output, or bind-mounting a host directory over `/var/log/nginx`.  Either of those would let you use a host-based log-management solution that doesn't need special support inside the container.

Comment: This way can do it well: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to wrap the nginx image's entrypoint file in an entrypoint of you own, whose job is to start the `cron` service and then hand off to the standard docker-nginx entrypoint.  The `nginx` image uses the entrypoint `/docker-entrypoint.sh`, so we just need to start `cron` and pass the command to that script, using an entrypoint like:

```
#!/bin/bash

cron && /docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

Here's a simple Dockerfile that creates the necessary entrypoint and overrides the entrypoint in the base image:

```
FROM nginx

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        cron \
        && \
    echo '#!/bin/bash\n\ncron && /docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"' >> entrypoint-wrapper.sh && \
    chmod +x /entrypoint-wrapper.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint-wrapper.sh"]

# Have to reset CMD since it gets cleared when we set ENTRYPOINT
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

### Sample run

```
$ docker run --name nginx-cron --detach nginx-cron
34301405f7b426022d9c286ff4e00f1c58570d76c5aba6b9f1c50ef698829976
$ docker exec nginx-cron service cron status
cron is running.
$ docker exec nginx-cron service nginx status
nginx is running.
```