# Add cronjob and flask server in same docker image

Tags: python, docker, cron, dockerfile

I am trying to add cronjob and flask server in same docker image. My Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM python:alpine3.9
RUN apk --update add build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev curl
ADD crontab.txt /crontab.txt
ADD cronscript.sh /cronscript.sh
COPY entry.sh /entry.sh
RUN chmod 755 /cronscript.sh /entry.sh
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /crontab.txt
RUN /bin/sh /entry.sh
WORKDIR /
RUN mkdir app
COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
COPY *.py /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod +x main.py
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD [ "main.py" ]
```

cronscript.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Starting cronjob"
curl http://localhost:4000/health
echo "Completed cronjob"
```

crontab.txt

```
*/15 * * * * /cronscript.sh >> /var/log/cron.log
```

entry.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# start cron
/usr/sbin/crond -l 2
```

This does not start cronjob. I see no data in `/var/log/cron.log` after waiting for an hour.

Where as if I move the line `/bin/sh /entry.sh` in my flask main function. Everything works.

flask main function

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  os.system("/bin/sh /entry.sh")
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=4000, debug=True)
```

Is there a way I can get this cron job working from Dockerfile itself and not python code? This feels like a hack.

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container

Comment: It'll be easier to run two separate processes in two separate containers (they can be based on the same image).  The `ENTRYPOINT` you have doesn't make sense, though, and makes this harder; write a single `CMD python main.py` (with no `ENTRYPOINT`) and you can separately `docker run your-image crond -f` overriding that command.

Comment: @DavidMaze That should work. But I was checking if having cronjob with something else is at possible in single Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add extra line to make it cron valid. Please check (https://blog.knoldus.com/running-a-cron-job-in-docker-container/)