# The Docker container does not run the crontab

Tags: docker, cron

I build a Docker image to run a crontab file:

```
RUN apt-get install -y cron
RUN touch /usr/local/learnintouch/cron.log
COPY learnintouch.cron /usr/local/learnintouch/
RUN chmod 0644 /usr/local/learnintouch/learnintouch.cron \
  && sudo crontab /usr/local/learnintouch/learnintouch.cron
```

It has an ENTRYPOINT to run a `start.sh` file which contains:

```
# Run the crontab
sudo service cron start
```

The `learnintouch.cron` file contains:

```
* * * * * echo "Hello cron" >> /usr/local/learnintouch/logs/cron.log 2>&1
```

But the log shows nothing.

Only if I connect in the container and run the `start.sh` file manually, that is, as the `root` user, does the log show the `Hello cron` message.

When logged in the container, the files have the `apache` user:

```
root@72f59adb5324:/usr/local/learnintouch# ll
total 2852
drwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache    4096 May 11 19:42 ./
drwxr-xr-x  1 root   root      4096 May  3 20:10 ../
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache       0 May 11 18:56 cron.log*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache    1057 May 11 19:34 start.sh*
root@72f59adb5324:/usr/local/learnintouch# whoami
root
```

I reckon it's a user permissions issue.

UPDATE: I tried replicating the issue with a Dockerfile as in:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.10

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y sudo \
  && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get clean

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/learnintouch/
RUN apt-get install -y cron
COPY learnintouch.cron /usr/local/learnintouch/
RUN chmod 0644 /usr/local/learnintouch/learnintouch.cron \
  && crontab /usr/local/learnintouch/learnintouch.cron

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/cron", "tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

After building the image:

```
docker build -t stephaneeybert/cronissue .
```

and running the container:

```
docker run --name cronissue -v ~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/logs:/usr/local/learnintouch/logs stephaneeybert/cronissue
```

the `cron` started working fine and the issue would NOT show up.

So I reckoned the issue could lie within the `docker-compose.yml` file I use.

I thus tried running with the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  cronissue:
    image: stephaneeybert/cronissue
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/logs:/usr/local/learnintouch/logs"
```

with the Docker Swarm command:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml cronissue
```

And again the cron started working fine and the issue would NOT show up.

So I finally added the `user: "${CURRENT_UID}:${CURRENT_GID}"` property that I also have in my project as in:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  cronissue:
    image: stephaneeybert/cronissue
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/logs:/usr/local/learnintouch/logs"
    user: "${CURRENT_UID}:${CURRENT_GID}"
```

And this time, the `cron` did NOT work and the issue showed up.

The issue shows up ONLY when I run the container with the host user.

As a side note, I also tried opening the file permissions but it did not change anything:

```
  && chmod a+x /usr/bin/crontab \
  && chmod a+x /usr/sbin/cron \
```

UPDATE: I ended up using `supercronic` instead of `cron` as it works fine in containers.

```
# Using supercronic as a cron scheduler
# See https://github.com/aptible/supercronic/
COPY supercronic-linux-amd64 /usr/local/learnintouch
COPY learnintouch.cron /usr/local/learnintouch/
RUN chmod 0644 /usr/local/learnintouch/learnintouch.cron
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)

Comment: No, in fact, that's where I went to first and from what I created my own attempt :-)

Comment: In general, running `service` in a container won't do anything (because there is no service manager running). If you want to start something like the cron daemon, start it yourself (e.g., `ENTRYPOINT ["crond", "-n"]` (noting, of course, that the name of your cron daemon and the arguments it expects to run in the foreground will vary depending on your distribution).

Comment: @larsks Enlightening. But in fact, I had started with the simple `cron` command before switching to a `service cron start` command. It also didn't run the `cron`. Now I tried a `sudo cron` command but it didn't run it either.

Comment: Running `cron` via `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` -- with the proper flags such that it runs in the foreground -- works just fine. If you've tried that and it didn't work, please update your question to show a `Dockerfile` that reproduces the problem and we can probably help figure things out.

Comment: @larsks I added a `Dockerfile` and a `docker-compose.yml` illustrating the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the command in `ENTRYPOINT` doesn't make sense. You've got:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/cron", "tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

It looks like you're trying to combine two commands here (`cron` and `tail -f /dev/null`), but you can't just mash together commands like that. It looks like you're using the `tail -f /dev/null` to try to keep the container running after `cron` background itself, but that's unnecessary -- looking at the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/cron.8.html), we can use the `-f` flag to `cron` to keep it in the foreground, so that becomes:

```
ENTRYPOINT ['/usr/sbin/cron', '-f']
```

Fortunately, the way you've got things configured, `cron` is just ignoring the unknown arguments (you can run `cron this is a test -f` and it works) so you're accidentally doing the right thing.

> The issue shows up ONLY when I run the container with the host user.

The `cron` daemon is designed to run as `root`. If I try starting your image as a non-`root` user, for example using your `docker-compose.yml` that sets the `user`, I get:

```
cronissue_1  | cron: can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied
```

And even if you fix that problem by changing the directory ownership, `cron` will still fail:

```
$ cron -f
seteuid: Operation not permitted
```

You'll need to run `cron` as `root`, or you'll need to find some other tooling if you really want to run a scheduler as a non-`root` user.

---

> As a side note, I also tried opening the file permissions but it did not change anything:
>
> ```
> && chmod a+x /usr/bin/crontab \
> && chmod a+x /usr/sbin/cron \
> ```

Note that the above commands are no-ops; both commands are *already*
executable by everyone so you haven't changed anything.

Comment: I run the container as the host user so as to write in the log mapped host volume. I guess I could ditch the volume mapping and run it as root then.