# How to effectively schedule a microservice?

Tags: python-3.x, microservices, scheduled-tasks

I have a python application, that performs some tasks. I run it inside a docker container.
I need to schedule this script to run every 30 minutes. Currently, I take this `30 min` as a command-line argument while running the script. I wrap my execution logic inside a forever running while loop that sleeps for 30 minutes. Is this pattern of running a microservice architecture pattern? Should I convert it into a flask API and schedule the API to run every 30 minutes?

Comment: For this task you can use crontab. For example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container

Answer (score 0):

You can use k8s cronjob which will work same like normal cronjob but it will run your container on scheduled time .
ref#
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/