# Permission Denied as root when writing to /proc/1/fd/1 in Docker

Tags: docker, cron, permissions

I have a container running `cron -f`, which stops the container from outputting to `stdout` as containers normally do. I need my cron jobs to output to `stdout` for datadog and `docker logs` to see it.

I got the idea to write to proc files from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46220104/5915915

With this, my cron's started failing. When I tried writing to the file manually inside the container, for example with

```
echo 'hi' > /proc/1/fd/1
```

I am told:

```
bash: 1: Permission denied
```

The result of `ls -l` is:

```
root@my-container:/proc/1/fd# ls -l
ls: cannot read symbolic link '0': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link '1': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link '2': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link '3': Permission denied
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar  8 23:46 0
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Mar  8 23:46 1
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Mar  8 23:46 2
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar  8 23:46 3
```

A similar problem has a solution in the comments by the op, but his files were somehow owned by his db user instead of root. This idea does not work for me. https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/imx8zr/permission_denied_when_write_to_proc1fd1/

How is `root`'s permission being denied? Or alternatively, is there a better way to get my cron's output to show in `stdout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way around this is to have the file be owned by a non-root user. This can be done by calling `cron -f` inside of a startup script from `CMD` after switching users.

At the end of my Dockerfile

```
USER worker
```

In my docker-compose:

```
cron_service:
  CMD: ["./start.sh"]
```

In start.sh

```
cron -f
```

Now the proc files created for the cron process will be owned by `worker`, which cron is able to write to.