# How to schedule a job in the background and start another process inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, cron, containers, sh

My question is quite close to other questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container) and [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/455192/testing-an-infinite-loop-in-the-background-within-docker) which use `cron` or an `infinite loop` to schedule single a job/process inside a docker container.

Both approaches work for me but my problem is a bit different: I would like to

1. schedule a job/process in the background
2. and subsequently start another process.

In my real world problem:

1. is an `ETL process` and
2. is a `Django instance` (websever).

How can I do this in a clean way?

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: A Docker container only runs a single process.  So if you can't run your scheduled task in the same _process_ as your Web server, then you should run it in a separate container, which the first question you link to describes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using `docker-compose` based on the following [article](https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/9033/how-to-use-cron-with-your-docker-containers/).

It basically overrides the entrypoint in another service as follows in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: demo-image:latest
    volumes:
      - data:/app-data
  cron:
    image: demo-image:latest
    command: [ "cron -f" ]
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - data:/app-data

volumes:
  data:
```

My example `Dockerfile`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM python:3.9

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install cron
COPY my-crontab /etc/cron.d/my-crontab
RUN chmod 0744 /etc/cron.d/my-crontab
RUN crontab -l | { cat; cat /etc/cron.d/my-crontab } | crontab -
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

My example `cronjob` file with an important hint that took me hours of bugtracking:

```
* * * * * echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# must be ended with a new line "LF" (Unix) and not "CRLF" (Windows)
```

I found this solution much cleaner because it only uses one process per container.