# how to perform cron jobs every 5 minutes inside docker

Tags: docker, cron, dockerfile

I want to perform cron jobs every minute for feeds.sh and every 5 minutes for reminder.sh inside docker container. It was able to run every minutes for feeds.sh. However for reminder.sh,  it cannot run every 5 minutes as it keep throwing the error `/bin/ash: */5: not found` inside the docker container.

The following code is shown as below :

```
FROM alpine:latest

# Install curlt 
RUN apk add --no-cache curl

# Copy Scripts to Docker Image
COPY reminders.sh /usr/local/bin/reminders.sh
COPY feeds.sh /usr/local/bin/feeds.sh


# Add the cron job
RUN echo ' *  *  *  *  * /usr/local/bin/feeds.sh &&  */5  *  *  *  *    /usr/local/bin/reminders.sh' > /etc/crontabs/root

# Run crond  -f for Foreground 
CMD ["/usr/sbin/crond", "-f"]
```

Comment: Consider using a [`docker`-friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75353647/52499) `cron` implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it on a separate line.

When you use && with cron, it's expecting multiple cron jobs to add for the same cron frequency.

eg.

`0 * * * * a && b`

Hence why it says "*/5 not found" because that's the `b` above - it thinks it's a cron script to run.

Add your */5 * * * * script on a separate line in its own command.

Comment: i try to add two different commands  `RUN echo ' *  *  *  *  * /usr/local/bin/feeds.sh' > /etc/crontabs/root
RUN echo ' */5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/reminders.sh' > /etc/crontabs/root `. For reminders.sh, it did run every 5minutes. However , the cron jobs does not work for feeds.sh. It only show reminder.sh cronjobs every 5minutes

Comment: @GavinJuen You need to use >>, not >.

`>` will overwrite the whole crontab. >> will append

Comment: Thank you so much it helps!!! i will upvote your answer

Comment: Awesome, glad it's working! Hope your project goes well!

Comment: @Azzaro i posted another question regarding my project. I wonder if u could have look at it. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Updated Docker File to run both every minute and every 5 minutes

```
FROM alpine:latest

# Install curlt 
RUN apk add --no-cache curl

# Copy Scripts to Docker Image
COPY reminders.sh /usr/local/bin/reminders.sh
COPY feeds.sh /usr/local/bin/feeds.sh

# Add the cron job

RUN echo ' *  *  *  *  * /usr/local/bin/feeds.sh' >> /etc/crontabs/root
RUN echo ' */5  *  *  *  * /usr/local/bin/reminders.sh' >> /etc/crontabs/root

# Run crond  -f for Foreground 
CMD ["/usr/sbin/crond", "-f"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  supercronic:
    build: .
    command: supercronic crontab
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.17
RUN set -x \
    && apk add --no-cache supercronic shadow \
    && useradd -m app
USER app
COPY crontab .
```

`crontab`:

```
*/5 * * * * date
```

```
$ docker-compose up
```

More info in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75353647/52499).