# running cron in foreground in Docker container produces no output

Tags: docker, cron

I want to run some cron jobs in a Docker container and send the output to stdout. I read this post: [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)

To try this out with a simple example, I created a demo crontab:

my-crontab:

```
* * * * * date > /dev/stdout 2> /dev/stderr
# empty line
```

Then I run an interactive shell inside a Docker container based on the image my scripts will need:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint bash python:3.10.3-bullseye

/# apt update
/# apt install cron
/# crontab < my-crontab
/# cron -f
```

If I wait 60 seconds, I expect to see some output to the console attached to the container once every minute. But there is no output.

Finally, I found the output in /var/spool/mail/mail. Here is one message:

```
From root@5e3c82cb3651 Tue May 10 20:04:02 2022
Return-path: <root@5e3c82cb3651>
Envelope-to: root@5e3c82cb3651
Delivery-date: Tue, 10 May 2022 20:04:02 +0000
Received: from root by 5e3c82cb3651 with local (Exim 4.94.2)
    (envelope-from <root@5e3c82cb3651>)
    id 1noW5S-0000SA-0T
    for root@5e3c82cb3651; Tue, 10 May 2022 20:04:02 +0000
From: root@5e3c82cb3651 (Cron Daemon)
To: root@5e3c82cb3651
Subject: Cron <root@5e3c82cb3651> date > /dev/stdout 2> /dev/stderr
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
Message-Id: <E1noW5S-0000SA-0T@5e3c82cb3651>
Date: Tue, 10 May 2022 20:04:02 +0000

Tue May 10 20:04:01 UTC 2022
```

Then it looks like /bin/sh is completely ignoring the shell redirection in the crontab.

Comment: `/dev/stdout` points at wherever the process's stdout would normally go; for something launched by cron, that will by default be captured and sent out via email.  You might try `/proc/1/fd/1` instead to target the main container process's stdout, but you might not be allowed to do that.  (`>/dev/stdout 2>/dev/stderr` redirect stdout and stderr to where they're already going; it doesn't really do anything.)

Answer (score 1):

@DavidMaze answered this in his comment (above - can't find a link to it). Redirecting to /proc/1/fd/1 and /proc/1/fd/2 (for stderr) totally works. Thank you, David.

Nevertheless, that's counterintuitive. The filesystem nodes /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr already exist as symlinks that point to /proc/1/fd/1 and /proc/1/fd/2, respectively, independent of cron. Why wouldn't `cmd > /dev/stdout` and `cmd > /proc/1/fd/1` be interchangeable in a crontab?

Comment: /dev/stdout is already captured by cron itself, so you cannot use that. Hence you have to use another file descriptor

Comment: @oligofren You mean that 2 processes can't write to the same file? That is [not true](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/2e3c30250c35a4139d5a24a4f9a95249). Lawrence, what makes you think that `/dev/stdout` points to `/proc/1/fd/1`? It points to `/proc/self/fd/1`. But each task is run in a separate process, and for a task, `self` is never 1.

Answer (score 0):

`cron` was written quite a while a ago. And expectedly, it's not, say, `docker`-friendly. It expects tasks to produce no output. And if they do, that is considered an error, and `cron` tries to email the responsible person about it. There are some tricks to make `cron` tasks' output to be seen in `docker logs`, but why not choose a `docker`-friendly `cron` implementation?

One of which is [`supercronic`](https://github.com/aptible/supercronic):

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  supercronic:
    build: .
    command: supercronic crontab
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.17
RUN set -x \
    && apk add --no-cache supercronic shadow \
    && useradd -m app
USER app
COPY crontab .
```

`crontab`:

```
* * * * * date
```

A [gist](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/427172d62edc9ac6596d5382365e78b5) with a bit more info.

Another good one is [`yacron`](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/66fc314d2e38395ff5778398c233e017), but it uses YAML.

[`ofelia`](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/d135bfabbe1b4798ad2fcfbca11a907c) can be used, but they seem to focus on running tasks in separate containers. Which is probably not a downside, but I'm not sure why I'd want to do that.

But if you insist on traditional ones, you can find a couple in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75353647/52499).

Answer (score 0):

I reconsidered and decided that putting cron in a Docker container was an “anti-pattern”. On the one hand, it’s tempting to package it all as a service that “just works” when you run the container, but if anything happened to me it might be hard for whoever takes over to figure out how to stop a recurring task (I’m the only developer and Docker user in a team of network engineers). Instead, I just use crontab in a host account used by my team, and redirect the container’s stderr to a log file on the host. That way everything can be found easily for those who know where to look.