# Saving cron output to log within Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, command-line, cron

I've been trying to set cron up within a Docker container. It is now working fine. What I want now is a log file.

This is my crontab:

```
* * * * * python /code/data_etl.py > /proc/1/fd/1 2> /proc/1/fd/2
```

My Dockerfile CMD is `CMD ["cron", "-f"]`.

I was only able to get this working by following the answer here
[How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container/46220104#46220104)

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe the `f` flag is running cron in the foreground, rather than as a background process.

However, I'm not sure why this line `> /proc/1/fd/1 2> /proc/1/fd/2` is really necessary, and therefore, don't know how to amend it so that I can store a log file in my Docker container.

Answer (score 1):

`> /proc/1/fd/1` redirects `stdout` of your `python` process (your task) to `stdout` of the process with PID 1 (which is the `crod` daemon). `2> /proc/1/fd/2` redirects `stderr` of your task to `stderr` of the `cron` daemon.

Unless you do that, the output of your task won't appear in `docker logs`. And this trick works provided you run your tasks as `root`.

But doesn't that seem kind of tricky? Why not use a [`docker`-friendly `cron` implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75353647/52499)?

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning! You should be try to change your parameters in cron file to below:

```
* * * * * python /code/data_etl.py > /proc/1/fd/1
```

Only you need one of these, i think is unnecessary use `2> /proc/1/fd/2`

Let me know your result! Have a great day!

Comment: Hi. Not sure that's what I'm after. I'm really just looking for a way to store cron output to a file, whilst not breaking what I already have in place.

Comment: Oh okey, sorry for that. I understand other thing. Well i edit my answer and try it.

Comment: Unless you specify `> /proc/1/fd/1`, you won't see `stdout` output of your task in `docker logs`. Unless you specify `2> /proc/1/fd/2`, you won't see `stderr` output of your task in `docker logs`. More on it in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75354118/52499).