# why Cronjob in docker container not working

Tags: docker, cron, dockerfile, debian

I created a Docker image with Dockerfile for executing a script like `get_date.sh` on the container but it's not working.

`get_date.sh` contains:

```bash
date
date +"%FORMAT"
var=$(date)
var=`date`
echo "$var">>/var/log/tito_time.log
```

Dockerfile:

```bash
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER docker@ekito.fr
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron && apt-get install nano
COPY get_date.sh  /etc/cron.d/get_date.sh
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/get_date.sh
RUN crontab -l | { cat; echo "* * * * * bash /etc/cron.d/get_date.sh"; } | crontab -
CMD cron
```

The image is created correctly. Running `crontab -l` in a container shell gives me:

```
root@92ce260aeb21:/# crontab -l
* * * * *  bash /etc/cron.d/get_date.sh
```

crontab doesn't execute `get_date.sh` on the container.

Comment: How are you starting the container?

Comment: I think the problem is with how you add the cronjob. As the `crontab -l` does not list the schedule in your example. If I start a container with latest ubuntu and use your command to add it, and then read it with `crontab -l` I get `* * * * * bash /etc/cron.d/get_date.sh`. Where in your output, the stars (schedule) are missing. Though I don't have a solution for it now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)

Comment: @Dennis van de Hoef - Xiotin there are stars i forgot to put when i copy past

Comment: Using traditional `cron` implementations under `docker` is tricky. Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75353647/52499).