# cron service isn't started after restart of my docker app

Tags: docker, cron, rhel

Hi I got a docker compose file... with php-apache.
In this image I haven't cron... so I installed inside.

Whenever I shut down my lab and restart the whole cron service is down.
I always have to start it with "service cron start"

How can I make it always persistent and autostart on restart?
Thanks, Alen

```
 php-apache:
    image: ${phpapache}
    container_name: php-apache 
    hostname: php-apache
    restart: always
    volumes:
       - /etc/app/latest:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Comment: `service` doesn't usually work inside containers; do you mean that starting a container somehow stops the cron daemon on the host?  Are you fundamentally asking [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)  (It's almost always in a separate container from your main application.)

Comment: Thanks David for your response... yes maybe it's better to go as you mention and use a dedicated cron docker app.