# Crontab doesn't run the python script inside a docker

Tags: python, docker, cron

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9


WORKDIR /mydir

# Set desired Python version
ENV python_version=3.8 \
        PYTHONPATH="/mydir/smart-git/smart-datascience/python_daemons/Virtual/app:/mydir/smart-git/smart-datascience/data/load/:/mydir/smart-git/smart-datascience/Andrew/Monitoring kalibratora/":$PYTHONPATH
RUN env

ENV TZ=Europe/Berlin
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezoneA

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
USER root
RUN pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron

ADD mydir-crontab /etc/cron.d/mydir-crontab

RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/mydir-crontab

RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/mydir-crontab


CMD cron && python3 /mydir/smart-git/smart-datascience/python_daemons/Virtual/app/app.py
```

Crontab file:

```
20 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3 /mydir/smart-git/smart-datascience/python_daemons/Virtual/app/jsonification.py
```

The `app.py` script works without any issues. However, the `jsonification.py` doesn't. I've tested `jsonification.py` for over 10 days of continuous runtime and it worked without issues so I'm assuming I messed up something with docker/crontab.

**EDIT:**
For additional context, `jsonification.py` runs some processing on data and then stores it to a `json` file (creates a new one if it doesn't exist and appends if it does).

Comment: Your container just exits as soon as "jsonification.py" is completed. (Here's why the suggestion in Alez answer works).  So, does this answer your question? [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking 2 Python scripts: one inside the cronjob and one with the last CMD command of the Dockerfile. Leave it only inside the cronjob.

So, replace the last line of the Dockerfile with

```
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

in order to execute the cron-job on container startup and see its logs.

Comment: It's not the same script though. I'm invoking `app.py` in the last line of the Dockerfile and I'm invoking `jsonification.py` inside the cronjob. Unless I misunderstood.

Comment: You're right. I updated slightly my answer to be more precise. Btw the solution remains the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't understand where I should put the line that runs the `app.py` then? That script should be running continuously inside the docker container and `jsonification.py` should run as per the cron rule. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: Nevermind, I had an import bug all along.