# How to run a cronjob on Amazon ECS without creating a new docker container instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, scheduled-tasks, amazon-ecs

I am trying to run a python script recurringly that sends out emails. The script retrieves information about emails etc from the database that my application's backend API uses. This backend is already deployed as a service in my ECS cluster. I am trying to set up a scheduled task but from what I understand it creates a new docker instance in order to run it. Is there a way to run this task in the already existing docker instance that is active at all times and acts as the API server.

I tried to create a scheduled task but from what it looks like it creates a new docker instance every time it runs and as the script is a short and nondemanding one this seems wasteful. Also I am not sure about Lambda functions as I need to access the database inside the ECS container.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to use any AWS scheduling feature, and just want to run a cron job inside the docker container directly. In that case, try searching for "Run cron in docker" and look at solutions like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I would say this calls for simply using cron on your host, but its not best practice to run multiple processes in a docker container.

What you could look at doing is using [EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-api-destinations.html) to call an endpoint on your host that triggers the script/process on a [schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/scheduler.html) to send out your emails.