# Run a script before Postgres docker container start

Tags: postgresql, docker, cron, containers

My goal is to extend the official docker image, but to also enable a cron job for running backups. I am able to achieve this by extending the Docker image and then ssh into the container and run the `cron` command manually. However, I'd like for this to happen automatically. Is there a way to ensure that the cron daemon is active upon container start?

I have tried the following two approaches without success:

1. Add a script to the `./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory. This doesn't work, first due to permission issues, second because these scripts seem to be run on database creation only and I want to run them every time the container is started.
2. Modify the `CMD`/`ENTRYPOINT` of the [official image](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/1a73ab671b5f0f18313726e734c76bf171385c32/15/bookworm/Dockerfile#L186) to first start the cron daemon and then fire up postgres. However, I was unable to get this to work.

The approaches for editing the Dockerfile included:

1. Set the `ENTRYPOINT` to `ENTRYPOINT ["cron && docker-entrypoint.sh"]`/`ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/cron && docker-entrypoint.sh"]`/`ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/cron && docker-entrypoint.sh"]`. However, the cron executable is not found:

```bash
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/usr/bin/cron && docker-entrypoint.sh": stat /usr/bin/cron && docker-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
```

2. Copy an executable script in the image with the following contents:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cron
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

This fails with

```bash
docker_compose_templates-latticeflow-db-1   | /root/startup_script.sh: line 3: /usr/local/bin/docker_entrypoint.sh: No such file or directory
```

which is weird, since this is the default entrypoint for the image.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried in 2 and what errors did you get?

Comment: Yes, will post in a bit.

Comment: Added the things that I tried.

Comment: A Docker container only runs a single process, in this case the database server.  It does not run daemons.  You can run a separate cron container, or use the host's cron daemon and the `pgdump` tool from the host, connecting to the container's published port.  Since `pgdump` will happily connect to a remote database, there's no reason this needs to be "inside the database" _per se_.  [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container) has many more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Docker image with a custom entrypoint

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM postgres:latest

# Install cron
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/ 

# Copy your cron job
COPY my-cron-job /etc/cron.d/my-cron-job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/my-cron-job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/my-cron-job

# Copy the custom entrypoint
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/custom-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/custom-entrypoint.sh

# Set our custom entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/custom-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**Custom entrypoint**:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start cron in the background
cron &

# Start PostgreSQL in the background
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh "$@" &

# Keep the script running
tail -f /dev/null
```

**my-cron-job**: will contain your cronJob, something similar to:

```
* * * * * echo "Hello from Cron" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

Using the above Dockerfile will achive your goal.

Comment: This approach doesn't work. It hangs on a start and then exits on a restart.

Comment: Please explain what did you do exactly