# Cronjob not running inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, cron, dockerfile

I have python script which I want to execute inside docker container using shell scripts added on crontab.
I have created the following dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10.12

# create directory for logs
RUN mkdir /logs

# create a folder and copy code to it
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# make python and shell script executable
RUN find . -name "*.py" -exec chmod +x {} \;
RUN find . -name "*.sh" -exec chmod +x {} \;

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron && apt-get install -y vim

# Copy the cron file to the container
COPY cronfile.cronjob /etc/cron.d/cronfile.cronjob

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cronfile.cronjob

# Apply the cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cronfile.cronjob

# create log file
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# start the cron daemon
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

here is the cronfile.cronjob content:

```
* * * * * echo "Hello world" `date` >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
40 19 * * * /app/crons/test.sh >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

inside app/crons directory I have test.sh shell script.

When I am checking the cron servive using command: `service cron status`
it is showing running status.
on using command: `crontab -l` 
it is showing the cronfile.cronjob content inside crontab
but still the cronjobs are not executing.

Not been able to understand the problem here.

I want the cron to execute the cronjobs as mentioned inside the cronfile.cronjob.
I already tries many methods but not been able to understand the issue
I have tries the following links help resources but nothing is working out.
[solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)
[solution 2](https://lostindetails.com/articles/How-to-run-cron-inside-Docker)
[solution 3](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-cron-job)

Answer (score 0):

I've stripped down your docker file to the contents available to me so I can reproduce your issue, here is it:

```
FROM python:3.10.12

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron && apt-get install -y vim

# Copy the cron file to the container
COPY cronfile.cronjob /etc/cron.d/cronfile.cronjob

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cronfile.cronjob

# Apply the cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cronfile.cronjob

# create log file
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# start the cron daemon
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

I saw that actually cron job was executed, checked it in */var/log/cron.log*, but there wasn't any output in *docker logs*.

As mentioned in one of linked solutions, you have to change a little bit redirects in *cronjob* file:

```
* * * * * echo "Hello world" `date` > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```

It redirects output to process *stdout* and *stderr* via handles opened by *cron*. Where *1* stands for pid of a main docker process (*cron*)