# How to start the ATD service automatically in docker container?

Tags: php, docker, apache, mariadb

My ATD service in the container is not started up automatically. How can I solve this? What am I doing wrong?

My docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.8" 
services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build: './php'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_OVERRIDE=true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - mariadb
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html/

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxx
      MYSQL_USER: frank
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxx
      MYSQL_DATABASE: radiostation
    ports:
      - "8889:3306"

  phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      container_name: phpmyadmin
      links:
        - mariadb
      environment:
        PMA_HOST: db
        PMA_PORT: 3306
        PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 8082:80
```

My PHP Docker file

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

RUN apt-get update && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN apt update && apt install at -y && apt install wget -y
```

I tried everything, but I couldn't succeed.

```
CMD atd start -> not working
CMD service atd start -> not working
```

Comment: A Docker container is a wrapper around a single process; they don't "run services", and commands like `service` generally don't work.  You probably need to run this in a separate container.  Also see for example [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container).