# Cron service doesn't want to start automatically on a debian postgres container

Tags: docker, cron, debian

I have a debian docker container which by default runs postgre 16 with pgroonga extension on it.

Now I would like to start the cron service on this container, in order to be able to manage the logs, generated by the pgroonga extension, using logrotate.

I was able to install the required packages, but I am not able to start the cron service during the container startup. If I remote connect to the container, after it starts, I am  able to manually start the cron service, issuing "systemctl enable cron" or just "cron". So there is no problem with the cron service from what I can tell.

My docker file looks like this:

```
FROM groonga/pgroonga:3.1.5-debian-16

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y logrotate && apt-get install -y systemctl && apt-get install -y cron

RUN systemctl enable cron
```

I've also tries CMD["systemctl enable cron"] , CMD["cron"] but with these the postgres won't start at all.

An error I was seeing with the CMD option was :

```
mw-db_1              | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 346: exec: systemctl start cron: not found
```

Any idea how I can start the cron service and also have the postgres service starting properly at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a cron job inside a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)

Comment: I'm not seeing anything that I haven't tried, in that post.

Comment: There is no service manager running inside your container. You can't "enable" a service. A program will only run if you start it explicitly. If you want to start both `cron` and `postgres`, then you will need to explicitly start both `cron` and `postgres` (possibly by starting one in the background, and running the other in the foreground).

Comment: Alternatively, you probably don't need to run `cron` and `postgres` in the same container -- if you store the logs in a Docker volume, you can share that between multiple containers. This way you can have a dedicated `postgres` container and a dedicated `cron` container.

Comment: @larsks I had that option in mind too, as my last option. But if possible, I would prefer to have both cron and postgres run in the same container, that way I don't have to care about dependencies.