# How to run a cron job inside a docker container for execute python file?

Tags: python-3.x, cron, dockerfile

I am trying to run a cronjob inside a docker container that invokes a python3 script.

i'm using 'crontab', example.py,

How can I do this?

```
my crontab file:

`# START CRON JOB
* * * * * python3 /app/Projeto_NPS/src/scripts/hello.py > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
# END CRON JOB`
```

Comment: What issue are you encountering? Perhaps this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container