Simple cron job with docker does not run correctly
I wrote this reproducable repository to run a cron job with docker. Run it with command docker compose build && docker compose up. It restarts itself and does not print 'Hello world' every minute as expected.
https://github.com/brunolnetto/cron-docker
Thanks for all the fishes!

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44642583/610979 - the problem is that you're running cron as your container's CMD, and cron exits immediately, thus ending the container's lifetime. Either use a different command (e.g. tail -f), or run cron in the foreground with cron -f

It keeps attached to current terminal. However, it does not output the 'Hello world'.

The first issue you have is that to keep the cron command running, you should add the -f option. But when you do that, there's something weird going on where it assumes that the crond daemon is running and tries to find the PID of it using /var/run/crond.pid. crond isn't running, so the cron command fails.
After fiddling around with your Dockerfile, I came up with this modified Dockerfile that runs.
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron
RUN echo '* * * * * echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1' > cron-config
RUN crontab cron-config
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
CMD cron -f


Thanks! I have more challenges with docker, but it is ok for now.
